# Formatting of linked inline code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

When referring to a LaTeX package I like to codeify the name, i.e., I write `amsmath` to make a distinction with normal text. Now when you want to link to the CTAN page of this package, you write

```
[`amsmath`][1]
```

resulting in [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). As one can see, no visual clue of it being a link.

Am I wrong to do this? In the light of [Automatic links to the CTAN catalogue?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/automatic-links-to-the-ctan-catalogue) I feel that it might be a good idea though.

Edit: To make it a bit clearer: this is a feature request, as in (if it is not deemed an inappropriate use of `code` and links) a change to the stylesheet. This could do the trick I guess

```
a, a code
{
    color: #145680;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover, a:hover code
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited, a:visited code
{
    color: #3989bb; 
}
```

if my CSS isn't too rusty. I'm not sure though whether `a:hover code`, i.e. the `:hover` acting as a parent element's pseudo class selector works good in all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can make code link text to be the same as regular link's. For example:

[image]

it'd be as simple as

a code { #83741E; }

Comment: Indeed, the underline behaviour wouldn't need any special handling. But the colour you're using at the moment is for the meta part, I was actually going for the parent's style.

Comment: @Pieter the same will apply to parent site as well.

Comment: I have put the fix in, should be in the next deployment.

Comment: The change is on prod now.