# Linking to CTAN best practice?

Tags: discussion

In the absence of an answer to [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/73/215), what is the best practice when linking to a package on CTAN? I have an irrational dislike of the CTAN "catalogue" version, so I tend to link to the actual CTAN page. However, the catalogue is more user friendly. Or should we link to package documentation by default?

What do you think should be the standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard practice, such as it is, does tend to be to use the catalogue links. I guess this is because they are relatively easy to type. I always go for

```
[`somepackage`][1]

[1] http://ctan.org/pkg/somepackage
```

which also seems to be the way a number of other people handle things. Now, whether this is the 'accepted' approach I wouldn't like to say. I guess the best plan is to see what alternatives come up!