# Why doesn't maths render as maths?

Tags: support, faq

On some other SE sites, code in between dollar signs gets rendered as mathematics (using MathJaX, I believe).  This doesn't seem to work here?  Why not?  And how do I get round it?

Comment: This question covers the approach as it is now. If you wish to discuss the availability/utility (or otherwise) of MathJax on the TeX - LaTeX site, please open a separate meta thread.

Comment: Further information: the [original feature request](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/can-we-turn-off-math-tex-please) that led to MathJax being deactivated on this site.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On this site, we want to see the actual code far more often than we want to see the rendered output, so MathJaX is **not** enabled for this site.  If you want to show the result of some input, you need to create an image of the output and upload it.  One of the simplest methods of getting an image from your code is to use the [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package (see [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible) for more details).  To upload it, click on the "add image" button at the top of the text box (the box symbol next to the one with the 1s and 0s) and, if you have at least 10 reputation points, you will be able to upload the image and have it embedded in your question/answer.

Comment: A probably even simpler method to get an image of the output is to make a screenshot.

Comment: i agree and I totally get the point. Simply indicate that sometimes it could be interesting to have that ability, for example when you want to indicate in the text that you are referring to a specific result label. I've missed that ability on a few occasions.