# Often referenced questions

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, big-list

### Quick links <sub><sup>(alphabetically)</sup></sub>

[Additional (math) operators, relations and so on](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6835/) ❧
[Beamer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7539/36296) ❧
[Bibliographies and citations](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2428/) ❧
[Classes and class options](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6374/) ❧
[Core concepts](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9019/) ❧
[Cooperation with editors and non-TeX applications](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9037/) ❧
[Correct centering](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2423/) ❧
[Cross-referencing, including hyperref](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2648/) ❧
[Databases](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7294/) ❧
[Date and Time](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7622)
❧
[Debugging & log files](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8525)
❧
[Disaster recovery](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8825)
❧
[Documentation & Definition of commands](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3552)
❧
[Figure/table numbering](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/) ❧
[Figure/table (float) positioning](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2421/) ❧
[Fonts & font encoding](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2494/) ❧
[Front matter](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437/) ❧
[Images/Graphics](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4261/) ❧
[Indexing and Glossaries](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6619/) ❧
[Installing, updating, restoring, other system operations](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2426/) ❧
[Lists, itemize, enumerate](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8485/) ❧
[Math environments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2425/) ❧
[Meta TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6581/64454) ❧
[Naming](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2887/) ❧
[Old font macros](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2424/) ❧
[Page layout and output](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9004) ❧
[Sectioning and blocks of text](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5938/) ❧
[Source code related issues](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2429/) ❧
[Spacing and pagination, hyphenation, line breaking](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2474/) ❧
[Symbols](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2427/) ❧
[Table formatting](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6539/) ❧
[Teaching/learning resources, and examples](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8477/) ❧
[Text as text](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7666/36296) ❧
[Theorems and friends](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4467/) ❧
[TikZ issues](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3972/)

---

I keep seeing the same bad coding styles being used in MWE or even recommended in answers or comments. There are also some FAQs (like the famous and repeatable asked how-to-place-my-figure-here question) which need to be linked to the appropriate existing question. Sometimes I have issues finding the related question quickly even if I already linked to it a couple of times before.

So I thought it would be good to have a collection of such often references questions sorted after topic in a meta post similar to our create [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430).

---

Questions should be listed after topic. Every topic as CW answer to this post.
Please use the following format:

```
## Topic Headline at Start of Answer Post

* [question title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/<question id>) [2 spaces] [linebreak]
 ``[question title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/<question id>)``
```

This way the question is provided as link (for quick access from this page) as well as markdown code suitable for comments (and as in-line link in a chat message). The URL can be received by using the `link` link below a question. There is also an [stackapps app](https://stackapps.com/q/2150/10230) ([modified by me](https://stackapps.com/a/3318/10230)) which produces this format. The include `/<user id>` should be removed to have the links in a neutral form. The two spaces and line break after the first line makes sure that the code starts at a new line.

Topic headers at the start of every answer post should be done using second order headlines, i.e. `## Topic`. The first order headlines are a little to large IMHO.

Comment: Great list: thanks Martin!

Comment: @doncherry: Good idea with the quick links, thank you!

Comment: @Jake: I was thinking to add a bullet-point list at the bottom myself, but it didn't looked good. I like the top list in this form much better.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I'm not sure if the format with several categories in separate answers is working out. We have 26 questions in 12 answers, that's about two per category, and whenever I want to add a question, I'm having trouble finding the right category. One answer with broader categories might be a better solution and more flexible?

Comment: @JosephWright Would it be useful to add http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i here? If so, does it belong with Installing or Fonts? I hesitate to just add it because it may be only frequently referenced by me and I don't want to use this meta-post for self-advertising ....

Answer (score 41):

### Installing, updating, restoring, other system operations

#### Installing/updating the TeX distribution 
 (TeX Live, MikTeX, etc.)

- [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)
  `[How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)`
- [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447)
  `[How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447)`
  (covers Admin *versus* 'normal' user issues)
- [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)
  `[How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)`

#### Contents of TeX Live subsets

- [Differences between texlive packages in Linux](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504566) 
  `[Differences between texlive packages in Linux](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504566)`

#### Installing packages

- [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)
  `` [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137) ``
- [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063)
  `[How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063)`
- [How can I install a package on MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484084)
  `[How can I install a package on MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484084)`
- [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016)
  (an extensive community-edited answer)
  `[How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016)`
- [How do I add a `.sty` file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252)
  `` [How do I add a `.sty` file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10252) ``
- [How to install a package from an older version of TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089)
  `[How to install a package from an older version of TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25089)`

#### Installing fonts

- [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423)
  `[Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423)`

#### Finding things (lost files, information about packages, etc.)

- [Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304)
  `[Which package version am I using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304)`
- [Find the right package for missing files in TeXlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274536) 
  `Find the right package for missing files in TeXlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274536)`
- [LaTeX can't find my .bst file. How do I show it the way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/)
  `[LaTeX can't find my .bst file. How do I show it the way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/)`
- [TexStudio Autosave Recovery Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188079/) 
  `[TexStudio Autosave Recovery Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188079/)`
- [Compiling ArXiv source code of articles with images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504640) 
  `[Compiling ArXiv source code of articles with images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504640)`

#### Compilation

- [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791) 
  `[Speeding up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791)`
- [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3) 
  `[Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3)`

Answer (score 37):

### Symbols (*see also* [Fonts & Font encoding](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2494))

**Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive symbols list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/)** 
`[Comprehensive symbols list](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/)`

#### Symbols in math

Alphabetic (including with diacritics)

- [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)
  `[How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)`
- [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124) 
  `[What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124)`
- [How do you get \mathbb{1} to work (characteristic function of a set)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26637) 
  `[How do you get \mathbb{1} to work (characteristic function of a set)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26637)`
- [Turn \mathbb characters bold in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199333) 
  `[Turn \mathbb characters bold in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199333)`
- [How to change all \vec{} to \bf{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258218) 
  `[How to change all \vec{} to \bf{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258218)`
- [Automatically crossing 7's and Z's in mathematical formulae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34500) 
  `[Automatically crossing 7's and Z's in mathematical formulae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34500)`
- [Why can I only use some capital greek letters inside my equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1368) 
  `[Why can I only use some capital greek letters inside my equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1368)`
- [What is the capital Greek letter for tau?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111544) 
  `[What is the capital Greek letter for tau?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111544)`

(Mostly) Non-alphabetic

- [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)
  `[Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)`
- [How to get only one symbol from a symbol package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174814) 
  `[How to get only one symbol from a symbol package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174814)`
- [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595)
  `[How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595)`
- [How to write partial differential equation (Ex. dQ/dt=ds/dt) with real partial derivative signs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225523) 
  `[How to write partial differential equation (Ex. dQ/dt=ds/dt) with real partial derivative signs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225523)`
- [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432) 
  `[How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432)`
- [make summation sign big without affecting the size of lower bound of summation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200661) 
  `[make summation sign big without affecting the size of lower bound of summation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200661)`
- [How can I have a bigger integral (\int) delimiter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414) 
  `[How can I have a bigger integral (\int) delimiter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414)`
- [“Evaluated at” bar for derivatives: \Bigr, \biggr, or \left…\right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294499) 
  `[“Evaluated at” bar for derivatives: \Bigr, \biggr, or \left…\right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294499)`
- [Math symbol question: Vertical bar for ''evaluated at …''](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40160) 
  `[Math symbol question: Vertical bar for ''evaluated at …''](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40160)`
- [Vertical bar turning horizontal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193216) 
  `[Vertical bar turning horizontal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193216)`
- [How to color math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21598) 
  `[How to color math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21598)`
- [Double square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107252) 
  `[Double square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107252)`
- [Is there a way to do an "upside down" \widehat?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44235) (\widecheck) 
  `[Is there a way to do an "upside down" \widehat?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44235)`
- [Typesetting old fashioned factorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117497) 
  `[Typesetting old fashioned factorials](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117497)`
- [What is the LaTeX code for an "open semicolon"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125012) (\fcmp) 
  `[What is the LaTeX code for an "open semicolon"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125012)`

#### Symbols in text or code

- Producing output for special characters [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580) 
  `[Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580)`
- [What is the best way to use quotation mark glyphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531) 
  `[What is the best way to use quotation mark glyphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531)`
- [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529) 
  `[Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529)`
- [Non-curly quotes in code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238298) (or a verbatim environment) 
  `[Non-curly quotes in code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238298)`
- [Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312) 
  `[Correctly typesetting a tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312)`
- [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363) 
  `[How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363)`
- [How to typeset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex/hat)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77646) 
  `[How to typeset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex/hat)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77646)`
- [Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632) 
  `[Underscores in words (text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48632)`
- [Why is tilde not available out of the box in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320855) 
  `[Why is tilde not available out of the box in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320855)`
- [What is the difference between \dots and \ldots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77737) 
  `[What is the difference between \dots and \ldots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77737)`
- [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)
  `[How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)`

Comment: Couldn't really find a good category for [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919) ... feel free to place it elsewhere.

Answer (score 37):

### Bibliographies and citations

#### General problems

- [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) 
  `[Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)`
- [Latex Why are my references empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350785) 
  `[Latex Why are my references empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350785)`
- [Sort thebibliography by citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17354) 
  `[Sort thebibliography by citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17354)`
- [Get BibTeX to ignore citation numbering in a figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44554) 
  `[Get BibTeX to ignore citation numbering in a figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44554)`
- [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128)
  `[Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128)`
- [BibTeX loses capitals when creating `.bbl` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772)
  `` [BibTeX loses capitals when creating `.bbl` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772) ``
- BibTeX: [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745) 
  `[How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745)`
- Multiple/distributed bibliographies 
  [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660) 
  `[Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660)`
- [Are comments discouraged in a BibTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262282) (don't use `%`) 
  `[Are comments discouraged in a BibTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262282)`
- [Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458) 
  `[Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8458)`
- [How to adjust the breaking in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308) 
  `[How to adjust the breaking in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308)`

#### Specific elements of a bib entry

- [What is the safe character set for a BibTeX label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581901) 
  `[What is the safe character set for a BibTeX label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581901)`
- [BibTeX: abbreviate name to 2 or 3 letters (not 1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26332) 
  `[BibTeX: abbreviate name to 2 or 3 letters (not 1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26332)`
- Re authors: [Error in .bib entry, “Too many commas”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343163) 
  `[Error in .bib entry, “Too many commas”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343163)`
- Presentation of author name: [I need to cite a classical author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347774) 
  `[I need to cite a classical author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347774)`
- [Underscore in bibtex url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383678) 
  `[Underscore in bibtex url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383678)`
- [How to deal with bibliography items containing long URLs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4213)
  `[How to deal with bibliography items containing long URLs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4213)`
- [Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134281/) 
  `[Line breaks of long URLs in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134281/)`
- [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/36296) 
  `[Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/36296)`

#### Bibliography tools and packages

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)
  `[bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)`
- [Cleaning up a .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76420) 
  `[Cleaning up a .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76420)`
- [What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)
  `[What to do to switch to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091)`
- [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)
  `[biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)`
- [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)
  `[What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)`
- [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/)
  `[Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/)`
- [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/) 
  `[Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/)`
- [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821) 
  `[Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821)`
- [Natbib sorting and citation order by appearance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61877) 
  `[Natbib sorting and citation order by appearance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61877)`
- [Is there an (easy) way to create or personalize .bst files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96174)
  `[Is there an (easy) way to create or personalize .bst files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96174)`
- [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447)
  `[Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447)`

Answer (score 28):

### Figure/table (float) positioning

- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)
  `[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)`
  This is the "official", general post.
- [Image from \includegraphics showing up in wrong location?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16207) 
  `[Image from \includegraphics showing up in wrong location?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16207)`
- [Getting two pictures to appear on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134162) 
  `[Getting two pictures to appear on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134162)`
- [Split subfigures over multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278727) 
  `[Split subfigures over multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278727)`
- [Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850) 
  `[Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850)`
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)
  `[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)`
- [Where do I place floats in the source?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40080)
  `[Where do I place floats in the source?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40080)`
- [Why does a figure capture a whole page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12409)
  `[Why does a figure capture a whole page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12409)`
- [avoid that figure gets its own page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68516)
  `[avoid that figure gets its own page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68516)`
- [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582) 
  `` [Center figure that is wider than `\textwidth`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582) ``
- [Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309454) 
  `[Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309454)`
- [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243) 
  `[Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243)`
- [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181) 
  `[Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181)`
- [warning: Text page X contains only floats.” How to suppress this warning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223149) 
  `[warning: Text page X contains only floats.” How to suppress this warning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223149)`

#### Full-width * floats at the bottom of a multicolumn page

- [Put a table* at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3527) 
  `[Put a table* at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3527)`
- [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)
  `[How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)`
- [How to add two two-column figures in the top and bottom of the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344763) 
  `[How to add two two-column figures in the top and bottom of the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344763)`

Answer (score 27):

### Correct centering

- [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651)
  `[Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651)`
- [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650)
  `` [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650) ``

Answer (score 26):

### Math environments

#### *See also* [Symbols](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2427)

#### Questions involving coding

- Blank lines

  - [Syntax of Using Math Mode: Empty Lines (Beginner Question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338) 
    `[Syntax of Using Math Mode: Empty Lines (Beginner Question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338)`
  - [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)
    `[Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)`
- Preferred LaTeX coding

  - ["!Missing $ inserted" error using `amsmath` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128243)
    `` ["!Missing $ inserted" error using `amsmath` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128243) ``
  - [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)
    `` [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) ``
  - [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510)
    `` [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510) ``
  - [Is the effect of dollar sign the same as `\textit`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345373) 
    `` [Is the effect of dollar sign the same as `\textit`?] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345373) ``
  - [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)
    `` [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196) ``
  - Using `align` for a one-line display vs. a multi-line environment

    [What is the difference between align and equation environment when I only want to display one line of equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239550) 
    `` [What is the difference between `align` and `equation` environment when I only want to display one line of equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239550) ``

    [`align` vs `equation`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321) 
    `` [`align` vs `equation`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321) ``
  - [How to make a box around an equation in align-environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193242) 
    `[How to make a box around an equation in align-environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193242)`
  - [When not to use `\ensuremath` for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34837) 
    `` [When not to use `\ensuremath` for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34837) ``
- Text strings in math

  - [Is there a preference of when to use `\text` and `\mathrm`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502) 
    `` [Is there a preference of when to use `\text` and `\mathrm`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502) ``
- Disappearing content following `[`

  - [`aligned` environment doesn't output first part in the bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281939) 
    `` [`aligned` environment doesn't output first part in the bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281939) ``
- Redefining math environments

  - [What is wrong with defining `\bal` as `\begin{align}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100138) 
    `` [What is wrong with defining `\bal` as `\begin{align}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100138) ``
  - [newenvironment: error with `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236666) 
    `` [newenvironment: error with `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236666) ``
  - [how to make shortcuts for the start and end of a “gather” environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373841) 
    `[how to make shortcuts for the start and end of a “gather” environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373841)`
  - [How do I embed a `gather` environment within a custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100212) 
    `` [How do I embed a `gather` environment within a custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100212) ``

#### Delimiters: `\left` / `\right` problems, sizing

- [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173740) 
  `[Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173740)`
- ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773) 
  `["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12773)`
- [What is the purpose of "\left.", i.e., "\left" followed by a period?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429437) 
  `[What is the purpose of "\left.", i.e., "\left" followed by a period?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429437)`
- [Automatic left and right commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1765) (using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`) 
  `[Automatic left and right commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1765)`
- [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612)
  `` [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612) ``
- [Linebreak between `\left` and `\right`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49890) 
  `` [Linebreak between `\left` and `\right`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49890) ``
- [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486)
  `` [Using `\left(` & `\right)` around `amsmath`'s `align` delimiter (“&”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160486) ``
- Why one should not [Replace regular parenthesis with stretching versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262752) 
  `[Replace regular parenthesis with stretching versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262752)`
- Delimiter sizes with `stix`/`xits` fonts:

  - [Wrong parentheses size in `\binom` with xelatex and unicode-math in `displaystyle`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269980) 
    `[Wrong parentheses size in \binom with xelatex and unicode-math in displaystyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269980)`
  - [Fix inconsistent matrix parentheses size in stix2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528604) 
    `[Fix inconsistent matrix parentheses size in stix2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528604)`
- Middle "delimiter":

  - [How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448) 
    `[How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448)`
  - [Why is \mid so called?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52901) 
    `[Why is \mid so called?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52901)`

#### Spacing, sizing and positioning (*see also* [Symbols](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2427))

- Superscripts, subscripts and limits

  - Need for braces around multiple-character script 
    (not the best question possible; looking for a better one) 
    [Math notation in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261616) 
    `[Math notation in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261616)`
  - [How to avoid using curly braces when placing a `\DeclareMathOperator` command in subscript or superscript, while preserving spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437380) 
    `` [How to avoid using curly braces when placing a `\DeclareMathOperator` command in subscript or superscript, while preserving spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437380) ``
  - [non-kludgey left subscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407) and superscripts 
    `[non-kludgey left subscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407)`
  - [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542) 
    `[Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542)`
  - [Superscripts appear in various weird places in fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337328) 
    `[Superscripts appear in various weird places in fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337328)`
  - [`\atop` vs. `\substack` for multiple lines under a sum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153490) 
    `` [`\atop` vs. `\substack` for multiple lines under a sum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153490) ``
  - [LaTeX adjusting `\sum` limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89447) 
    `` [LaTeX adjusting `\sum` limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89447) ``
  - [Bad spacing of exponents in denominator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357998) 
    `[Bad spacing of exponents in denominator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357998)`
- Operators in text and display

  - [Making the product operator (pi caps) with the extremes above and below the symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301677) 
    `[Making the product operator (pi caps) with the extremes above and below the symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301677)`
  - [Show inline math as if it were display math (and vice versa)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824) 
    `[Show inline math as if it were display math (and vice versa)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824)`
  - [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12344) 
    `[Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12344)`
- Spacing around and between display equations

  - [How can I decrease spaces between equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32918)
    `[How can I decrease spaces between equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32918)`
  - [Remove vertical space around align equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237762) 
    `[Remove vertical space around align equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237762)`
  - [Spacing of consecutive equations versus a single `gather`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80511)
    `` [Spacing of consecutive equations versus a single `gather`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80511) ``
  - [How to globally change the spacing around equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69662)
    `[How to globally change the spacing around equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69662)`
- Aligning things properly in multi-line displays

  - Applies to all multi-line display environments defined by `amsmath`: 
    [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954) 
    `` [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954) ``
  - Diagrammatic layout of `align...' environments 
    [Problem using aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590213) 
    `[Problem using aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590213)`
- Under- and overbraces vs. delimiters (size and relative placement)

  - [How can I get text underneath an `\underbrace`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30090) 
    `` [How can I get text underneath an `\underbrace`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30090) ``
  - [`\underbrace` in denominator with () {} (howto)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145865) 
    `` [`\underbrace` in denominator with () {} (howto)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145865) ``
  - [`\underbrace` across `align` tabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288419) 
    `` [`\underbrace` across `align` tabs]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288419} ``
  - [How to prevent an underbrace, with a subscript, from affecting the sizes of delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435697) 
    `[How to prevent an underbrace, with a subscript, from affecting the sizes of delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435697)`
  - [`\underbrace` disturbs balanced vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496902) 
    `` [`\underbrace` disturbs balanced vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496902) ``
- Horizontal spacing in math

  - [Bad spacing of math letters within italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3490) 
    `[Bad spacing of math letters within italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3490)`
  - Spacing around math atoms (table) 
    [What's the right space ...?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777) 
    `[What's the right space ...?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81777)`
  - [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the `aligned` environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482) 
    `` [Why is there a `\,` space at the beginning of the `aligned` environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482) ``
  - [Preserve spacing while using `align` with `amsmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76423) 
    `` [Preserve spacing while using `align` with `amsmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76423) ``
  - [Alignment of multiple `align`-blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263455) 
    `` [Alignment of multiple `align`-blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263455) ``
  - [How to get less spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41913) 
    `[How to get less spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41913)`
- Vertical alignment

  - [Inconsistent superscript placement in $q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y}$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298295) 
    `[Inconsistent superscript placement in $q_x^{n_x} q_y^{n_y}$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298295)`
  - Uneven vertical positioning of `\vdots`

    - [Mathematical optimization problem doesn't look good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286701) 
      `[Mathematical optimization problem doesn't look good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286701)`
    - [Excess vertical space in \vdots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528774) 
      `[Excess vertical space in \vdots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528774)`
    - [Wrong (too much) vertical space above \vdots in small matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207056) 
      `[Wrong (too much) vertical space above \vdots in small matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207056)`
    - [Vertical alignment of dots in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144913) (`\vdotswithin`) 
      `[Vertical alignment of dots in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144913)`

#### Displays and related multi-line environments

- Interaction between display and surrounding text

  - [Use of `\small` to resize a math display affects the baseline stretch of the preceding paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382898) 
    `` [Use of `\small` to resize a math display affects the baseline stretch of the preceding paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382898) ``
  - [New-lines in TeX source. What are the rules?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345230) 
    `[New-lines in TeX source. What are the rules?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345230)`
- How multi-line environments work

  - [Difference between `align` and `alignat` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844) 
    `` [Difference between `align` and `alignat` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844) ``
  - [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47560) 
    `[How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47560)`
  - [Using `\allowdisplaybreaks` locally for a single chapter / single equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102173) 
    `[Using \allowdisplaybreaks locally for a single chapter / single equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102173)`
- Multi-line displays treated as list items

  - [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394) 
    `` [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394) ``
  - [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141) 
    `` [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141) ``
- Equation numbering

  - [Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951) 
    `` [Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951) ``
  - [Vanilla equation numbering examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98401)
    `[Vanilla equation numbering examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98401/5764)`
  - [Equation number with an apostrophe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132401)
    `[Equation number with an apostrophe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132401)`
  - [Show equation number only once in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17528)
    `[Show equation number only once in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17528)`
  - [How can I position equation numbers always to the left side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35497)
    `[How can I position equation numbers always to the left side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35497)`
  - [How can I put equation number both on the left and on the right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430977)
    `[How can I put equation number both on the left and on the right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430977)`
  - [Block of equations with only some being subequations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313367)
    `[Block of equations with only some being subequations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313367)`
  - [Numbering a set of horizontally distributed equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112796)
    `[Numbering a set of horizontally distributed equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112796)`
  - [How do I turn off equation auto numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2597) 
    `[How do I turn off equation auto numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2597)`
- Text within a display block (`\intertext` et al.)

  - [How can I break an `align` environment for a paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9577) 
    `` [How can I break an `align` environment for a paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9577) ``
  - [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665) 
    `[How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665)`
  - [Multiline `\text` in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125917) 
    `` [Multiline `\text` in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125917) ``

#### Matrices

- General

  - [Where is the `\matrix` command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447) 
    `` [Where is the `\matrix` command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447) ``
  - [How to create a matrix with 20 columns in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95162) 
    `[How to create a matrix with 20 columns in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95162)`
  - [How do I left-align entries in a matrix with `\begin{matrix}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45001) 
    `` [How do I left-align entries in a matrix with `\begin{matrix}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45001) ``
  - [`\bordermatrix` with brackets [ ] instead of parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054) 
    `` [`\bordermatrix` with brackets `[ ]` instead of parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054) ``
  - [Multiple `\underbrace`s that span overlapping columns in matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146084) 
    `` [Multiple `\underbrace`s that span overlapping columns in matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146084) ``
  - [Error with square bracket in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34466) 
    `[Error with square bracket in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34466)`
- Subdivided matrices

  - [Create a block matrix with four quadrants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230500) 
    `[Create a block matrix with four quadrants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230500)`
  - [Seemingly simple block matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216454) 
    `[Seemingly simple block matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216454)`

- [How to add vertical and horizontal lines in an array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399728) 
  `[How to add vertical and horizontal lines in an array(https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399728)`
- [How to write the given block matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514862) 
  `[How to write the given block matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514862)`
- [A question about typesetting a partitioned matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308292) 
  `[A question about typesetting a partitioned matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308292)`
- [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028) 
  `[Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028)`

#### Miscellaneous

- [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43008) 
  `[Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43008)`
- [How to fine-tune hyphenation for mix of math and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348410) 
  `[How to fine-tune hyphenation for mix of math and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348410)`
- [How to negate a specific symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996) 
  `[How to negate a specific symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996)`
- [How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40253) 
  `[How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40253)`
- [Is there a designated symbol for the negative sign in, say, -16?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79141) 
  `[Is there a designated symbol for the negative sign in, say, -16?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79141)`

Answer (score 25):

### Source code related issues

#### Examples -- big lists

- [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468) 
  `[Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468)`

#### Control sequence naming and input format

- [Macro naming best practice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48195) 
  `[Macro naming best practice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48195)`
- [Is \10 allowed as a control-sequence name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141888) 
  `[Is \10 allowed as a control-sequence name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141888)`
- [*Why* does TeX not allow numbers in command names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598250) 
  `[*Why* does TeX not allow numbers in command names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598250)`
- [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718) 
  `[Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718)`
- [Cyrillic letters in command names with PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439543) 
  `[Cyrillic letters in command names with PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439543)`
- [How can I use Chinese characters (or more generally, Unicode characters) as a macro name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191152) 
  `[How can I use Chinese characters (or more generally, Unicode characters) as a macro name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191152)`
- [Are there alternative methods to "_" for subscripting in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269701) 
  `[Are there alternative methods to "_" for subscripting in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269701)`
- [Why do people use unnecessary braces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1914) (with `\newcommand`) 
  `[Why do people use unnecessary braces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1914)`

#### Package loading order

- [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863)
  `` [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863) ``

#### Reusable code and packaging

- [Creating a default preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278817) 
  `[Creating a default preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278817)`

#### Use of percent signs (`%`)

- [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?
   (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453)
  `` [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) ``
- [(La)TeX — What does the '%' character do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/566578) 
  `[(La)TeX — What does the '%' character do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/566578)`
- [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946)
  `` [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946) ``
- [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)
  `` [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922) ``

#### LaTeX internal commands with at signs (`@`)

- [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an `@` in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/)
  `` [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an `@` in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/) ``
- [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351)
  `` [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351) ``

#### Use of `\@` (backslash-at)

- [What is the proper use of @ (i.e., backslash-at)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22561) 
  `[What is the proper use of \@ (i.e., backslash-at)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22561)`

#### Other non-alphabetic commands, e.g., `&`

- [What does a double ampersand (&&) mean in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159723) 
  `[What does a double ampersand (&&) mean in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159723)`

#### Verbatim inclusions

- [When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790) 
  `[When should one use \verb and when \texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2790)`
- [Underscore is shorter for `ttfamily`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534383) 
  `[Underscore is shorter for ttfamily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534383)`
- [Displaying `\begin{verbatim}…\end{verbatim}` inside the environment verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51031) 
  `` [Displaying `\begin{verbatim}…\end{verbatim}` inside the environment verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51031) ``
- [End \verbatim command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247404) 
  `[End \verbatim command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247404)`

#### LaTeX3 syntax

- [What do `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108696)
  `` [What do `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108696) ``

#### Over- and underfull boxes

- [What does “overfull hbox” mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35) 
  `[What does “overfull hbox” mean? (Why is there a black mark at the end of a line?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35)`
- [What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138) 
  `[What are underfull hboxes and vboxes and how can I get rid of them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138)`

#### Not ending paragraphs with a double backslash

- [Best choice between using `\\` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495)
  ``` [Best choice between using ``\\`` or leaving space after each paragraph to end the paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66495) ```
- [What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" actually mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334246) 
  `[What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" actually mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334246)`
- [When to use `\par` and when `\\`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664)
  ``` [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664) ```
- [Strange “There's no line here to end” error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89010) 
  `[Strange “There's no line here to end” error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89010)`
- [Manual linebreak with justification but without empty line afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127644)
  `[Manual linebreak with justification but without empty line afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127644)`

#### Nested square brackets

- [LaTeX: optional arguments with square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84595)
  `[LaTeX: optional arguments with square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84595)`
- [`]` inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495) 
  `[ ] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495)`

#### Number parsing

- [Use of `\relax` after `\ifnum`...`\fi` construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137207)
  `` [Use of `\relax` after `\ifnum`...`\fi` construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137207) ``

#### Unicode (UTF-8) source

- [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25391) 
  `[The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25391)`
- [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067) 
  `[utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067)`
- [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34604) 
  `[Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34604)`

Comment: I have issues finding a right title here. Feel free to change it. Not sure if there are more questions which fall under this topic.

Comment: I'd suggest http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines as the canonical question about `%`, as it doesn't contain a second question about braces.

Answer (score 23):

### Cross-referencing, including hyperref

- [Hyperref: using abbreviated labels like Eq., but keep correct spacing after period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497152) 
  `[Hyperref: using abbreviated labels like Eq., but keep correct spacing after period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497152)`
- [Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823) 
  `[Remove ugly borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823)`
- [Link boxes obscure punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391004) 
  `[Link boxes obscure punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391004)`

- [Changing \url{...} font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261434) 
  `[Changing \url{...} font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261434)`

#### labels

- [Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)
  `[Understanding how references and labels work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280)`
- [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)
  `[Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)`
- [Link to arbitrary part of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280462) 
  `[Link to arbitrary part of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280462)`
- [Protecting references in section headings from capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162347) 
  `[Protecting references in section headings from capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162347)`
- [Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35043) 
  `[Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35043)`
- Using multiple `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` 
  [Difference between \footnote and the pair \footnotemark and \footnotetext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584721) 
  `[Difference between \footnote and the pair \footnotemark and \footnotetext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584721)`
- [Incorrect target of \label link produced by hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49061) (`\pageref`) 
  `[Incorrect target of \label link produced by hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49061)`

#### `hyperref` and bookmarks

- [What does the `hyperref` option `hypertexnames` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188)
  `` [What does the `hyperref` option `hypertexnames` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3188) ``
- [How to make clickable links and cross-references in PDFs produced by LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272)
  `[How to make clickable links and cross-references in PDFs produced by LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272)`
- [Making clickable links to sections with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180571) 
  `[Making clickable links to sections with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180571)`
- [Bad hierarchy given to `\appendix` by `hyperref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246235)
  `` [Bad hierarchy given to `\appendix` by `hyperref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246235) ``

Answer (score 21):

### Spacing and pagination, hyphenation, line breaking

- [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091) 
  `[Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091)`
- [Acceptable use cases for xspace; When will it fail?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180686) 
  `[Acceptable use cases for xspace; When will it fail?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180686)`
- [Do I have to care about bad boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830) 
  `[Do I have to care about bad boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830)`
- [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672) 
  `[Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672)`
- [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063) 
  `[Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)`
- [Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9550) 
  `[Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9550)`

#### Horizontal spacing

- [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353) 
  `[What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353)`
- [Meaning of `\quad`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119068) 
  `` [Meaning of `\quad`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119068) ``
- [How can I get letter spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17185) 
  `[How can I get letter spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17185)`
- Bad spacing between chapter/section numbers in table of contents or "lists of"
  [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841) 
  `[How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841)`
  [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)
  `[Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)`
- [Canonical way to typeset spacing in abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25831) 
  `[Canonical way to typeset spacing in abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25831)`

#### Vertical spacing

[Canonical way to typeset spacing in abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25831)

- [Double line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819) 
  `[Double line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819)`
- [Inconsistent line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454) (need for `\par`) 
  `[Inconsistent line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454)`
- [Why do I have to use `\par` if I change font size withing a group scope?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444039) 
  `` [Why do I have to use `\par` if I change font size withing a group scope?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444039) ``
- [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370) 
  `[Adding vertical space at the start of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370)`
- [Difference between \addvspace and \vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668162) 
  `Difference between \addvspace and \vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668162)`
- [\flushbottom vs \raggedbottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65355) 
  `[\flushbottom vs \raggedbottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65355)`
- [Placing a decorative separator in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237110) 
  `[Placing a decorative separator in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237110)`

#### Controlling page breaking and pagination

- What is the difference between [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/736) 
  `[\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/736)`
- [Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64284) 
  `[Is there a documentclass that produces 'endless' pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64284)`
- [Dynamic page break before section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/535641) 
  `[Dynamic page break before section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/535641)`
- `\enlargethispage`; also useful for getting rid of a bogus blank last page 
  [Squeeze some more lines on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32112) 
  `[Squeeze some more lines on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32112)`
- [How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227) 
  `[How can I add "page # of ##" on my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227)`
- Pages not breaking between successive adjacent (sub)section headings:
  [Overfull box and broken pagination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57861)
  `[Overfull box and broken pagination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57861)`
- Section divider that disappears at end or beginning of page:
  [Section break that displays content iff it occurs in middle of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186328) 
  `[Section break that displays content iff it occurs in middle of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186328)`

#### Special cases of long strings without hyphenation

- [How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441) 
  `[How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116441)`
- [How to wrap a word in line without hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100391) 
  `[How to wrap a word in line without hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100391)`
- [Splitting very big numbers over several lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13688) 
  `[Splitting very big numbers over several lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13688)`

#### Ordinary hyphenation

- [No hyphen for a single word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571) 
  `[No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571)`
- [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706) 
  `[Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706)`
- [Why can words with hyphen char not be hyphenated?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232) 
  `[Why can words with hyphen char not be hyphenated?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232)`
- [Globally enable hyphenation for the first word in a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276154) 
  `[Globally enable hyphenation for the first word in a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276154)`
- [Specifying multiple hyphenation exception lists for multi-lingual documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37934) 
  `[Specifying multiple hyphenation exception lists for multi-lingual documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37934)`
- [`texttt` is not breaking the line at existing hyphens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509140) 
  `` [`texttt` is not breaking the line at existing hyphens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509140) ``

#### Line breaking following a non-letter (e.g. a hyphen, slash or comma)

- [Help on dealing with items divided with slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121955) 
  `[Help on dealing with items divided with slash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121955)`
- [Wrapping long lines that contain no spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6171) 
  `[Wrapping long lines that contain no spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6171)`
- [How to get long \texttt sections to break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299) 
  `[How to get long \texttt sections to break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299)`

#### Paragraph shaping

- [What is the meaning of `\fussy`, `\sloppy`, `\emergencystretch`, `\tolerance`, `\hbadness`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241343) 
  `` [What is the meaning of `\fussy`, `\sloppy`, `\emergencystretch`, `\tolerance`, `\hbadness`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241343) ``
- [How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59122) 
  `[How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59122)`
- [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31555) 
  `[How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31555)`
- [Is there a tool that makes paragraphs into rectangles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116569) 
  `[Is there a tool that makes paragraphs into rectangles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116569)`
- [Avoid just nearly filled last lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41412) 
  `[Avoid just nearly filled last lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41412)`
- [Manual linebreak with justification but without empty line afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127644) 
  `[Manual linebreak with justification but without empty line afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127644)`
- [How to end paragraph text in an inverted pyramid shape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400285) 
  `[How to end paragraph text in an inverted pyramid shape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400285)`

Comment: there are many, many questions that ask why there isn't a space following some command; many could be combined, but most haven't.  i've just added the `[spacing]` tag to several that didn't have it (apologies for kicking them to the active list; most did have the tag already).  i think this concept is a good candidate for addition here, but can't decide among the pertinent questions.  some candidates (only the numbers, or i'll run out of space here): 14526, 17730, 17872 (closed ==> 17730), 25820, 29211, 44878, 79760 (closed ==> 14526), probably more

Comment: since you're the one who added this category, there are quite a few questions about *removing vertical space*, especially before chapter headings.  among them (numbers only):  17299, 39988, 43087, 44751, 70156, 79232, 109722, possibly more.  i didn't check for xrefs, but suspect that there are some.

Answer (score 21):

### Fonts & Font encoding (*see also* [Symbols](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2427))

- [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098) 
  `[Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425098)`
- [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)
  `[How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)`
- [Do fontsize environments exist?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258277)
  `[Do fontsize environments exist?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258277)`
- [How to determine the true size of a font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1401) 
  `[How to determine the true size of a font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1401)`
- [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (`¡`) or question mark (`¿`)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369)
  `` [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (`¡`) or question mark (`¿`)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369) ``
- [Free ornaments font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10941) 
  `[Free ornaments font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10941)`
- [Fatter Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100577) 
  `[Fatter Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100577)`

#### Questions about text fonts

- [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249)
  `[How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249)`
- [Small Caps and Bold Face](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411) 
  `[Small Caps and Bold Face](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27411)`
- [Why to use T1 font encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664)
  `[Why to use T1 font encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664)`

#### when using T1 font encoding, one should also

- [Load vector fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291)
  `[Load vector fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291)`
- [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291) 
  `[Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291)`
- [Using and interpreting pdffonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23104) 
  `[Using and interpreting pdffonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23104)`

#### hyphenation problems with accented characters

- [Why words with accented characters can't be automatic hyphenated with the default OT1 encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725)
  `[Why words with accented characters can't be automatic hyphenated with the default OT1 encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/725)`

#### using Times (the `times` package is obsolete)

- [How do I make my document use the Times font, both for the text and the math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669)
  `[How do I make my document use the Times font, both for the text and the math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669)`

Answer (score 20):

### Figure/table numbering

- [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333)
  `[Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333)`
- [How to get more subfigures than 26?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339699) 
  `[How to get more subfigures than 26?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339699)`
- [Using the same figure twice with no new number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200229) 
  `[Using the same figure twice with no new number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200229)`
- [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325) 
  `[Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)`

Answer (score 20):

### Old font macros

- [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
  `` [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516) ``
- [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)
  `` [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361) ``

---

I need the following text quite often, so I post it here:

```
Please note that the `\it`, `\bf`, etc. font macros are deprecated because
they do not use the new font selection scheme introduced with LaTeX2e.
Please use `{\itshape ..}`, `{\bfseries ..}` or `\textit{..}`, `\textbf{..}` instead.
See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)
and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361)
for more information.
```

Answer (score 19):

### Documentation & Definition of commands

- [How do I document my style files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13028) 
  `[How do I document my style files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13028)`
- [Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66) 
  `[Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66)`
- [A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26771) 
  `[A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26771)`

#### (La)TeX core

- [What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175) 
  `[What do newcommand, renewcommand, and providecommand do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175)`
- [Why are some LaTeX macros defined using \newcommand and some using \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150137) 
  `[Why are some LaTeX macros defined using \newcommand and some using \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150137)`
- Difference between optional and delimited arguments 
  [Are all commands with an optional argument fragile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497356) 
  `[Are all commands with an optional argument fragile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497356)`
- [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736) 
  `[What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736)`
- [What is a token?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104023) 
  `[What is a token?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104023)`
- [Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201) 
  `[Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201)`

#### `texdoc` and other online documentation

- [LaTeX, package documentation look-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62653)
  `[LaTeX, package documentation look-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62653)`
- [What is the quickest way to open the pdf-manual for a given tex function or program?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269521) 
  `[What is the quickest way to open the pdf-manual for a given tex function or program?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269521)`
- [Online searchable manual for TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11182) 
  `[Online searchable manual for TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11182)`

#### `texdef` & friends

- [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4327)
  `[Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4327)`
- [Display source for a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36955)
  `[Display source for a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36955)`

#### `source2e`, `macros2e`

- [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4790)
  `[Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4790)`

#### Miscellaneous (re)definition topics

- [Duplicating Environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116670) 
  `[Duplicating Environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116670)`

Answer (score 18):

### Naming

- [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)
  `[How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)`
- [Spaces in files names in `\input` or `\includegraphics`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191930) 
  `[Spaces in files names in \input or \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191930)`

Answer (score 13):

### TikZ

- [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)
  `[Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)`
- [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)
  `` [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372) ``
- [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347)
  `[Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347)`
- [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671) 
  `[Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671)`
- [how to keep a 1:1 scale with x and y axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61039) 
  `[how to keep a 1:1 scale with x and y axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61039)`
- [How can I strike-out arrows in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96967) 
  `[How can I strike-out arrows in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96967)`
- [Nesting of tikzpicture environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799) Don't!
- [Overlapping bars in pgfplots bar chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623945)

Comment: The `how to draw this scheme` link is down.

Comment: @Troy Thanks. The question had been closed (as duplicate, but the dupe was deleted as well), and later deleted. But neither that question nor the duplicate had any answers, so I just removed the entry from the post. If you're wondering, it was about drawing this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/multiplexer/

Answer (score 10):

### Table formatting

- [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902) 
  `[My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902)`
- [Error with square bracket in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34466) 
  `[Error with square bracket in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34466)`
- [extrarowheight vs arraystretch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114421)
  `[extrarowheight vs arraystretch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114421)`
- [Error: extra alignment tab has been changed to `\cr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37107)
  `` [Error: extra alignment tab has been changed to `\cr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37107) ``
- Hyphenate first word in cell: 
  [Multirow without centering (but multiple problems on my way there)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338354) 
  `[Multirow without centering (but multiple problems on my way there)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338354)`

  [Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394077) 
  `[Table column text exceeds column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394077)`
- [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441) 
  `[How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441)`
- [Table and \flushleft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346237) 
  `[Table and \flushleft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346237)`
- [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703) 
  `[How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703)`
- Unexpanded bold numbers for better alignment 
  [Align numbers by decimal point using siunitx and bfseries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318372) 
  `[Align numbers by decimal point using siunitx and bfseries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318372)`
- [How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6350) 
  `[How to disable pagebreak on \hline in longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6350)`
- [Rotated column titles in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32683) 
  `[Rotated column titles in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32683)`

Answer (score 9):

### Indexing and Glossaries

#### Generating External Files (Running `makeindex`/`xindy`):

- [Index not created in pdf output, even though idx file is present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36530)
  `[Index not created in pdf output, even though idx file is present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36530)`
- [List of Acronyms is not displayed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110095)
  `[List of Acronyms is not displayed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110095)`
- [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152)
  `[How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152)`
- [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099)
  `[Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099)`
- [TeXnicCenter and glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483383)
  `[TeXnicCenter and glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483383)`
- [latexmk reaches maximum runs when including new glossaries entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306995)
  `[latexmk reaches maximum runs when including new glossaries entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306995)`
- [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27824)
  `[Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27824)`
- [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233)
  `[What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233)`
- [makeglossaries hangs waiting for input on mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42999)
  `[makeglossaries hangs waiting for input on mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42999)`

#### Indexing:

- [Index with text different from structure text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461985)
  `[Index with text different from structure text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461985)`
- Scan document for keywords (no markup):
  [How to generate an automatic index (concordance) in a large file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/398627)
  `[How to generate an automatic index (concordance) in a large file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/398627)`
- [How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472)
  `[How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472)`
- [Use xindy to sort by bible book instead of ABC – or: How to add custom letter groups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356285)
  `[Use xindy to sort by bible book instead of ABC – or: How to add custom letter groups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356285)`

#### `acro` package:

- [How to define acronyms being part of another acronym? (using acro.sty)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130293)
  `[How to define acronyms being part of another acronym? (using acro.sty)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130293)`

#### `acronym` package:

- [Print acronym + full name in brackets at the first occurence of \ac{XYZ}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160665)
  `[Print acronym + full name in brackets at the first occurence of \ac{XYZ}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160665)`
- [How to escape ampersand in \acro command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47318) 
  `[How to escape ampersand in \acro command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47318)`

#### `glossaries` package:

- Lists and Sorting

  - No vertical gap between letter groups (`nogroupskip`):
    [How do I remove alphabetical grouping of acronyms in the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129294)
    `[How do I remove alphabetical grouping of acronyms in the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129294)`
  - [Glossary remains empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251171)
    `[Glossary remains empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251171)`
  - [Glossaries are not printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305370)
    `[Glossaries are not printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305370)`
  - [How to print all the acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367086)
    `[How to print all the acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367086)`
  - [Glossary WITHOUT location numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437772)
    `[Glossary WITHOUT location numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437772)`
  - [How to make the term “page” show in the Glossary list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365680)
    `[How to make the term “page” show in the Glossary list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365680)`
  - [Counter in front of the glossary name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480959) (enumerating top-level terms)
    `[Counter in front of the glossary name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480959)`
  - [Both sorted and unsorted glossaries with glossaries package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339361)
    `[Both sorted and unsorted glossaries with glossaries package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339361)`
  - [No printed glossaries when switching to \makenoidxglossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389875)
    `[No printed glossaries when switching to \makenoidxglossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389875)`
  - [Unusual sorting of greek letters and math mode symbols when using glossaries package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404724)
    `[Unusual sorting of greek letters and math mode symbols when using glossaries package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404724)`
  - [glossaries package reference non-glossary item in see also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191644)
    `[glossaries package reference non-glossary item in see also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191644)`
  - [When showing list of acronyms using glossaries package, only show those that are mentioned at least 4 times in the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437161)
    `[When showing list of acronyms using glossaries package, only show those that are mentioned at least 4 times in the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437161)`
- Linking

  - [Glossaries: Hyperlink to First Entry not List of Acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140666) 
    `[Glossaries: Hyperlink to First Entry not List of Acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140666)`
- Section Headings and Table of Contents

  - [Glossaries and custom section headings broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198140)
    `[Glossaries and custom section headings broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198140)`
  - [Include glossary in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98196)
    `[Include glossary in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98196)`
- Defining Terms/Symbols

  - [How can I have an acronym within another acronym with an uppercase first letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412062)
    `[How can I have an acronym within another acronym with an uppercase first letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412062)`
  - [Glossaries package with recursive terms (eg TCP/IP)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426863)
    `[Glossaries package with recursive terms (eg TCP/IP)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426863)`
  - [Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316777)
    `[Symbols with optional parameter in glossaries with \newglossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316777)`
  - [glossary with diacritic marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461428)
    `[glossary with diacritic marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461428)`
  - Including `\cite` on first use and in glossary:
    [Cite first instance of an acronym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461432)
    `[Cite first instance of an acronym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461432)`
- Formatting

  - [Position of powers/subscripts when using symbols/symbolslist via glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320507)
    `[Position of powers/subscripts when using symbols/symbolslist via glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320507)`
  - [glossaries: fail to expand in tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94885)
    `[glossaries: fail to expand in tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94885)`
  - [Abbreviation not shown correctly by long-short style (acronyms & glossary)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321177)
    `[Abbreviation not shown correctly by long-short style (acronyms & glossary)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321177)`
  - [Different formatting for acronyms and glossary entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303888)
    `[Different formatting for acronyms and glossary entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303888)`
  - [How to highlight text that includes glossaries and citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425432)
    `[How to highlight text that includes glossaries and citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425432)`
  - [Glossaries - expand acronyms for first-time use within each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435617)
    `[Glossaries - expand acronyms for first-time use within each chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435617)`
- Errors

  - [debug No room for a new \write problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154781)
    `[debug No room for a new \write problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154781)`
  - [New command within glossaries ›first‹ needs to be protected?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419368)
    `[New command within glossaries ›first‹ needs to be protected?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419368)`

#### `nomenclature` package:

- [Add column headings to nomentbl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374753)
  `[Add column headings to nomentbl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374753)`
- [How to make Two column nomenclature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321392)
  `[How to make Two column nomenclature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321392)`
- [How to make section in Nomenclature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223376)
  `[How to make section in Nomenclature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223376)`
- [nomencl package and vertical bar |](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31562)
  `[nomencl package and vertical bar |](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31562)`

#### General:

- [List of abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100354)
  `[List of abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100354)`
- [Best solution for acronyms, abbreviations, glossary and index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287080)
  `[Best solution for acronyms, abbreviations, glossary and index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287080)`
- [How to effectively use List of Symbols for a thesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348640)
  `[How to effectively use List of Symbols for a thesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348640)`
- [Differences between “xindy” and “makeindex”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199211)
  `[Differences between “xindy” and “makeindex”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199211)`
- [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796)
  `[MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158796)`

Comment: The perl scripts question isn't specific to glossaries, but I wasn't sure where else to put it.

Answer (score 7):

### Images/Graphics

- [Why do I get a black rectangle instead of my external picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112473)
  `[Why do I get a black rectangle instead of my external picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112473)`
- [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072)
  `[Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072)`
- [How to avoid showing the filename when using `graphicx`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4129)
  `` [How to avoid showing the filename when using `graphicx`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4129) ``
- [Placeholder for figure/includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44195) 
  `[Placeholder for figure/includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44195)`
- [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099) 
  `[How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099)`

Answer (score 7):

### Classes

#### General

- [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)
  `[Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)`

#### Class options

- [The article class ignores 14pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381/the-article-class-ignores-14pt)
  `[The article class ignores 14pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381)`
- [What does the draft mode change?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277) 
  `[What does the draft mode change?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49277)`

Answer (score 6):

### Front matter

#### Title page

- [Are there any packages providing collections of title pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244399)
  `[Are there any packages providing collections of title pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244399)`
- [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904)
  `[Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904)`
- [How to customize `\titlepage` in `beamer`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22346)
  `` [How to customize `\titlepage` in `beamer`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22346) ``
- [How to customize my titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)
  `[How to customize my title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)`
- [Inserting a picture in a title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214255) 
  `[Inserting a picture in a title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214255`

#### ToCs, Lists of figures/tables

- [Wrong page number in contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199599) 
  `[Wrong page number in contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199599)`
- [List of listings similar to list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306858) 
  `[List of listings similar to list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306858)`
- [Table of equations like list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173102) 
  `[Table of equations like list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173102)`
- Using optional argument to get different caption: 
  [Change caption in List of Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83392)
  `[Change caption in List of Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83392)`
- [How to force a Table of Contents to start new page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103998) 
  `[How to force a Table of Contents to start new page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103998)`
- [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10943) (memoir) 
  `[How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10943)`
- [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415) 
  `[Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)`
- [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841) 
  `[How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841)`
- [How to get dotted leads in ToC using book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303446) 
  `[How to get dotted leads in ToC using book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303446)`
- [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433) 
  `[Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433)` 
  Adding running head for unnumbered (starred) chapter: 
  `[Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91468)`
- [Adding word 'Table' before each entry in List of Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20337) 
  `[Adding word 'Table' before each entry in List of Tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20337)`
- [Add the word “Algorithm” before each entry in the List of Algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96969) 
  `[Add the word “Algorithm” before each entry in the List of Algorithms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96969)`

#### ToCs vs. bookmarks

- [Is it possible have the PDF bookmark level go deeper than the table of contents depth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18743) 
  `[Is it possible have the PDF bookmark level go deeper than the table of contents depth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18743)`

#### Other things that appear at the top of a document

- [Footnotes without numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170511) 
  `[Footnotes without numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170511)`

Answer (score 6):

### Beamer

- [Beamer overlay specifications for a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146908/36296)
  `[Beamer overlay specifications for a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146908/36296)`
- [Shortcuts for `\begin{frame}` are a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326787/36296)
  `` [Shortcuts for `\begin{frame}` are a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326787/36296) ``
- [Full width image in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142569/36296)
  `[Full width image in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142569/36296)`
- [How does beamer build the frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/36296)
  `[How does beamer build the frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/36296)`
- [Why does `! Missing $ inserted.` occur when using \verb in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197234) 
  `` [Why does `! Missing $ inserted.` occur when using \verb in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197234) ``
- [Verbatim in beamer showing error: "File ended while scanning use of @xverbatim."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140719) 
  `[Verbatim in beamer showing error: "File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140719)`
- [`\section` inside frame causes error due to nested frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244183) 
  `` [`\section` inside frame causes error due to nested frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244183) ``

Answer (score 5):

### Sectioning and blocks of text

- [Avoiding page breaks shortly after section/subsection headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2347)
  `[Avoiding page breaks shortly after section/subsection headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2347)`
- [Overfull box and broken pagination with page that contains only section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57857) 
  `[Overfull box and broken pagination with page that contains only section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57857)`
- [How can I put a line above a section heading and prevent a page break between?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5204)
  `[How can I put a line above a section heading and prevent a page break between?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5204)`
- [How can I number paragraphs (and sections) in the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55197)
  `[How can I number paragraphs (and sections) in the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55197)`
- [Change the word “Chapter” to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30757)
  `[Change the word “Chapter” to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30757)`
- [More section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30997/)
  `[More section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30997/)`
- [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333) 
  `[Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333)`
- [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862) 
  `[How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862)`

#### Including/excluding "sections" of input code

- [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246) 
  `[When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246)`
- [Why do \include and \input handle extension name differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319506) 
  `[Why do \include and \input handle extension name differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319506)`
- [Redefining \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108268) 
  `[Redefining \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108268)`
- [What are your best practices to compile only a part of the document or presentation (or how do you prepare the big ones)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142417) 
  `[What are your best practices to compile only a part of the document or presentation (or how do you prepare the big ones)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142417)`
- [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816) 
  `[Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816)`

#### Material stored in boxes

- [\setbox vs. \sbox and \savebox - What are the differences I need to know about?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46480) 
  `[\setbox vs. \sbox and \savebox - What are the differences I need to know about?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46480)`

Answer (score 5):

### Meta TeX.SE

- [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430) (pre-written common replies)  
  `[Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430) (pre-written common replies)`
- [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)  
  `[I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)`
- [What makes a good MWE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3343)  
  `[What makes a good MWE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3343)`
- [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  
  `[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)`
- [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866) 
  (preparing output of a MWE for posting here)
  `[Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866)`
- [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272) 
  `[Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272)`
- [How do I get latex output to show up on tex.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564) (read the comments) 
  `[How do I get latex output to show up on tex.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564) (read the comments)`

Answer (score 4):

### Additional (math) operators, relations and so on

- [Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)
  `[Define additional math operators to be typeset in roman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671/define-additional-math-operators-to-be-typeset-in-roman)`
- [How to create a new math operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573850) 
  `[How to create a new math operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573850)`

Answer (score 4):

### Text as text

- [Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296)
  `[Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296)`
- [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534) 
  `[Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534)`
- [Dynamically count and return number of words in a section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44618) 
  `[Dynamically count and return number of words in a section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44618)`
- [Superscript outside math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324) 
  `[Superscript outside math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324)`

Comment: "Text as text"?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Please feel free to rename it or suggest a suitable place within the existing categories. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43875228#43875228

Answer (score 3):

### Theorems and friends

- [Understanding the arguments in newtheorem e.g. \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155710) 
  `[Understanding the arguments in newtheorem e.g. \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155710)`
- [Theorem/Definition/Lemma problem — Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45817) 
  `[Theorem/Definition/Lemma problem — Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45817)`
- [Theorem numbering without the section and subsection numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347779) 
  `[Theorem numbering without the section and subsection numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347779)`
- [Theorem numbering in starred sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463247) 
  `[Theorem numbering in starred sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463247)`
- [How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966) 
  `[How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966)`
- [Citing inside theorem header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17107) 
  `[Citing inside theorem header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17107)`
- [How do you reprint a theorem, proposition, etc. in its entirety?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348867) 
  `[How do you reprint a theorem, proposition, etc. in its entirety?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348867)`
- [Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260) 
  `[Non italic text in theorems, definitions, examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38260)`

#### Placing an ending marker on non-proof environments

- [How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978) 
  `[How to make all theorem-like environments have an ending symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201978)`
- [Marking the end of a definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292371) (using `amsthm`) 
  `[Marking the end of a definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292371)`
- [Denoting the end of example/remark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16453) 
  `[Denoting the end of example/remark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16453)`

#### Proofs

- [Proof environment - line break after the “Proof.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85059) 
  `[Proof environment - line break after the “Proof.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85059)`
- [QED symbol on the same page as proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51781) 
  `[QED symbol on the same page as proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51781)`
- [Remove the qed symbol from only one proof environment, not all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88164) 
  `[Remove the qed symbol from only one proof environment, not all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88164)`

#### Lists in theorem environments

- [Itemizing theorem body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307199) 
  `[Itemizing theorem body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307199)`
- [Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17449) 
  `[Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17449)`
- [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717) 
  `` [`theorem` environment : interaction with `enumerate`/`itemize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319717) ``
- [How to change the (horizontal) distance between “Proof” and the first enumeration symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319949) 
  `[How to change the (horizontal) distance between “Proof” and the first enumeration symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319949)`

Answer (score 3):

### Databases

#### CSV / Text Files

- [Use datatool to read a row from a CSV file, then use the variables in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178904)
  `[Use datatool to read a row from a CSV file, then use the variables in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178904)`
- [Import CSV file generated from Excel To LaTeX with Datatool with accent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402291)
  `[Import CSV file generated from Excel To LaTeX with Datatool with accent](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402291)`

#### Relational Databases

- [pgfplots with SQL data](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327749)
  `[pgfplots with SQL data](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327749)`
- [Reading data from a relational database into a LaTeX table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48193)
  `[Reading data from a relational database into a LaTeX table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48193)`
- [Is it possible to connect a database to LaTeX to produce data-driven documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3697)
  `[Is it possible to connect a database to LaTeX to produce data-driven documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3697)`

#### General

- [Using an exercises package to build lots of Math/Calculus exercise lists and tests](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331594)
  `[Using an exercises package to build lots of Math/Calculus exercise lists and tests](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331594)`

Answer (score 3):

### Teaching/learning resources, and examples

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)
   
  `[What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner? ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)`
- [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/)
   
  `[LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/)`
- [List of books written in LaTeX with the source available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230526) 
  `[List of books written in LaTeX with the source available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230526)`
- [What research papers exist about TeX and friends?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423566) 
  `[What research papers exist about TeX and friends?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423566)`

Answer (score 3):

### Debugging & log files (see also [Source code related issues](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2429))

- `\documentclass` reported as undefined 
  ["Undefined control sequence" at beginning of any simple document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258617) 
  `["Undefined control sequence" at beginning of any simple document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258617)`
- [How to best debug LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538) 
  `[How to best debug LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538)`
- [Teach me to debug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309010) 
  `[Teach me to debug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309010)`
- [LaTeX debugging strategies and brace mismatching](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71384) 
  `[LaTeX debugging strategies and brace mismatching](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71384)`
- [What does  etc. mean in TeX's error message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500695) 
  `[What does <recently read> etc. mean in TeX's error message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500695)`
- [Latex \tracing commands list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491) 
  `[Latex \tracing commands list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491)`
- [Understanding the Log file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32213) 
  `[Understanding the Log file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32213)`
- [Unclean .aux file causes "file ended while scanning use of @newl@bel" error. Why is it not purged?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132551) 
  `[Unclean .aux file causes "file ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel" error. Why is it not purged?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132551)`
- [Write to log without wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4047) 
  `[Write to log without wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4047)`

Answer (score 2):

### Lists, itemize, enumerate

- [enumitem: Understanding the usage of asterisk and exclamation mark in setting the different lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490872) 
  `[enumitem: Understanding the usage of asterisk and exclamation mark in setting the different lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490872)`
- [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669) 
  `[Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669)`
- [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684) 
  `[Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684)`
- [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86054) 
  `[How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86054)`
- [How do we create a "continuous" list enumeration in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686246) 
  `[How do we create a "continuous" list enumeration in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686246)`
- [Add a space after itemize only if no text follows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571975) 
  `[Add a space after itemize only if no text follows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571975)`
- [LaTeX Sublist Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139547) (1.1, etc.) 
  `[LaTeX Sublist Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139547)`

See also

- [Front matter](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437),
  ToCs, Lists of figures/tables
- [Indexing and Glossaries](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6619),
  `glossaries` package, lists and sorting
- [Math environments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2425),
  Multi-line displays treated as list items
- [Theorems and friends](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4467),
  Lists in theorem environments

Answer (score 1):

### Date and Time

- [Query regarding usage of \date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88282)
  `[Query regarding usage of \date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88282)`

Answer (score 1):

### Disaster recovery

- [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503) 
  `[How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503)`
- [Are there any dangerous commands in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528262) 
  `[Are there any dangerous commands in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528262)`

Answer (score 0):

### Page layout and output

- [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063) 
  `[Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)`
- [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341) [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)
  `[How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341)`
- Insertion between columns: 
  [Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45958) 
  `[Implementing a pullquotes algorithm in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45958)`
- [Different column widths using multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89721) 
  `[Different column widths using multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89721)`
- [geometry, fancyhdr: \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} is not really centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874) 
  `[geometry, fancyhdr: \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} is not really centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33874)`
- [Including pdfpages renders rotated RevTeX 4.1 pdfLaTex output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266520) 
  `[Including pdfpages renders rotated RevTeX 4.1 pdfLaTex output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266520)`
- [How to insert a A3 PDF into a A4 Latex document with PDFLatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320459) 
  `[How to insert a A3 PDF into a A4 Latex document with PDFLatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320459)`
- [How to add an invisible watermark to PDF documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18943) 
  `[How to add an invisible watermark to PDF documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18943)`

#### Design examples and methods

- [How can I design a book cover?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17579) 
  `[How can I design a book cover?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17579)`
- [Fancy chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23477) 
  `[Fancy chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23477)`

Answer (score 0):

### Core concepts

- [What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260) 
  `[What are the various units (ex, em, in, pt, bp, dd, pc) expressed in mm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260)`
- [How does a TeX engine read and render the input stream?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157267) 
  `[How does a TeX engine read and render the input stream?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157267)`
- [How does TeX look for delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438359) 
  `[How does TeX look for delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438359)`

Answer (score 0):

### Cooperation with editors and non-TeX applications

#### Input (editors)

- [Is there a LaTeX wrapper for use in Google Docs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173317) 
  `[Is there a LaTeX wrapper for use in Google Docs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173317)`
- [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101) 
  `[When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101)`
- [How to invoke latex with the -shell-escape flag in TeXStudio (former TeXMakerX)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99475) 
  `[How to invoke latex with the -shell-escape flag in TeXStudio (former TeXMakerX)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99475)`

#### Output (PDF readers)

- [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155518) 
  `[Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155518)`
- [Why is 1.5 the default pdf version?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301386) 
  `[Why is 1.5 the default pdf version?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301386)`
- [Going "back" when using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51320) 
  `[Going "back" when using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51320)`

#### Other tools

- [Utility to Strip Comments from LaTeX Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83663) 
  `[Utility to Strip Comments from LaTeX Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83663)`
- [Grammar-checking tool for use with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6333) 
  `[Grammar-checking tool for use with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6333)`