# Thoughts on asking: How do I update my system?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A lot of questions on the main site are fixed by updating the distribution. At present, I don't think we have a comprehensive guide to updating the various distributions- the answers are spread about over the site, and hinted at in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq

So, what does the community think about having a question titled (something like), 'How do I update my distribution?', which could be linked in future answers. Perhaps we could have an answer for each of the main Operating Systems, with screenshots to help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested within the set of [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/5764) there is now a set of dedicated ["How do I update my distribution?"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2426/5764) posts. They include:

- [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)
- [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/5764)
- [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/5764)
- [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)