# Could a default comment about MWEs be added in reviews?

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface

#### Context

Recently I noticed a very common behavior about new users, they ask questions without providing MWEs.

As an example, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638024/citation-inconsistency) have more than one comment about lack of MWE.
[image]

While review questions I notice there are two default comments to `question unclear`and `question is too broad`.

[image]

#### Suggestion and question

I think adding a third one: `Please a MWE` with some default links would be quite useful.
Mainly the links:

- [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What makes a good MWE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe)
  I would say `question is unclear` is not specific about the lack of a MWE.

Could such feature be added to the `Share Feedback` default answers?

#### Justification

I know there is a link to `how to ask a good question here` on the right side

[image]

and (probably) a pop-up also appears for the very first question, as it showed to me here at my first question on `meta`.

[image]

Even with these tools, it seems many new users only understand the need for a MWE when a comment doing so is done. Creating a default comment with links would be a nice shortcut for the Community. It is easier than remembering the necessary links or searching for them. Those links are very useful and are (should be) used quite often.

---

*By the way*, I notice while typing I don't know if asking a question in Meta is the best way to present a suggestion of feature to the own website.

Comment: Well personally I think it is nicer and more convincing if there is a comment from a real person and not a "Community Bot" message. Also when I see such a question I'm already on the page and it takes me only about 10-20 seconds to type such a comment, I doubt that I would save much time by clicking though some review tools interfaces to find a template. message.