# How do I get latex output to show up on tex.SE?

Tags: discussion

This is a question from someone who is obviously quite new to tex.SE.  (BTW: this site is awesome!)  If I am writing a question, how do I get Latex output to show up on this site?  I know how to write the code, but I can't seem to get the results to display.

For example, I can type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 = 4
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but no output actually shows up.  Maybe I'm not explaining myself properly...please let me know if the question is not explained well.  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: This site does not convert your code into anything. It just shows it. When you see an image in a question or answer, that person have created the image on his/her own computer and uploaded it here.

Comment: That isn't possible. You need to take a screenshot of the output, upload it and use the image in your post.

Comment: Compile, open the pdf, take a screen shot, and press the rectangle next to `{}` (which you used for formatting codes) or press Cntrl+G.

Comment: You're probably thinking about an automated rendering of your input, similar to what MathJax does on (say) [math.se]. We don't have that here. You should follow the guidelines in [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764) That is, upload a picture of the output.

Comment: Depending on what you are compiling, use the standalone class or even a program like "LaTeXit" to make PDFs or PNGs that don't need to be cropped / trimmed / screenshotted.