# How to search for duplicates and handle them?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, close-reasons, search

Finding duplicates for a question, if they exist, is not always easy. What techniques can I use to find question duplicates? How should duplicates be handled?

Comment: Related http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/using-search-effectively and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/duplicate-questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, understand that having duplicates on a site is not a bad thing. They provide multiple landing points for visitors seeking a very similar solution. That's correct: Different questions leading to the same solution.

Perhaps someone is asking for the sum 12+15 while someone else is interested in finding the product 3×9. The example may seem trivial, but the principle carries through to a large number of possible duplicates. To rephrase while voting to close Q1 as a duplicate of Q2 doesn't necessarily mean that Q1 is asking the same as Q2. They may be asking for entirely different things.

Based on the above idea, I think about what would be required for an answer, and search for that. Additionally, in order to reduce the search results, adding appropriate tags help. Here are some examples:

Source: [Highlight text in verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268564/5764)

Duplicate search approach: I know [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) allows for escaping to change colour, so before quickly writing up and answer, lets search for [`fancyvrb [color] is:answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=fancyvrb%20%5bcolor%5d%20is%3aanswer), sorted by votes. Note the search specifically includes a reference to **answers only**. Searching through the first page reveals [Changing color of text snippet in a `verbatim` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91261/5764) which provides a viable solution.

Keys to finding duplicates include:

- Being patient (not just writing up a solution because you know the answer);
- Searching and perhaps refining this search using some [ninja search options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching);
- Switching to Google to search for solutions specific to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) by adding the search term `site:tex.stackexchange.com`. Google's search has often reveals far better hits than [the search engine provided by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/168244).

Meta references:

- [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/168244)
- [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/168244)
- [What constitutes a duplicate question? In particular, is a question a duplicate if the answer is contained in another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157464/168244)
- [“Close as duplicate” - what if only the answer is a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74080/168244)
- [Should I mark as duplicate if the question is answered elsewhere, but it's not the same question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213976/168244)
- [When is a duplicate question not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12182/168244)

Answer (score 6):

in addition to the suggestions provided by werner, there's also a
very nice meta question

[Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419)

which can be checked for possible duplicates.

if something is there, good.  if it's not, and you find a really great duplicate in your further search, add it to the list, to make the next person's job (or your own next search) easier.

and if a question you've found is *nearly* "perfect" (i.e. completely
covers all possibilities), don't feel shy about adding another answer,
or editing an existing one, to provide that missing bit.  or add a comment,
asking the person who gave the best answer to improve it by adding
what's missing.