# List of Perl scripts that have fixed the unescaped literal character problem

Tags: discussion, big-list

There are a number of useful Perl scripts distributed with TeX and friends. Perl deprecated the use of unescaped literal characters in regular expressions in version 5.16 and [now they're no longer permissible and will cause an error](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.26.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Unescaped_literal_%22%7B%22_characters_in_regular_expression_patterns_are_no_longer_permissible). Some of the Perl scripts in the TeX distributions suffered from this problem in the past but have now been fixed, but users are still picking up old versions that don't work with new versions of Perl.

Can we have a definitive list of all Perl scripts provided with TeX distributions that have fixed this issue (with version number) for easy reference whenever there's a new question that includes an error message like:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE
```

Comment: This question should be in the primary site, not meta.

Comment: @lhf It was intended as a reference question, like [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419). Perhaps it should've been a separate answer on that question, but it didn't quite fit the format.

Answer (score 11):

### Fixed

- [`biber`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biber) fixed version 2.8
  [Biber gets perl warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395654)
- [`latexdiff`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) fixed version 1.2.0 [Issue #61](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues/61)
- [`latexindent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) fixed version 2.2 
  [latexindent: it does the work, but emits these messages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323617)
- `makeglossaries` fixed in version 2.17 (distributed with [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) version 4.20 2015-11-30, `makeglossaries` version number is now synchronized with `glossaries.sty` as from v4.33).
  [Error with Perl interpreter and glossaries package on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376726)
- [`texdef`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdef) fixed in version 1.7c 2017-12-09 [How can I avoid this regex error when attempting to use texdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377168)
- [`xindy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindy) fixed version 2.5.1.20160104-2 [Bug report #826507](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826507)

### Fixed in Repository but Pending New Release

- [`makedtx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/makedtx)

### Not Yet Fixed

### Deprecated

(There won't be any new versions of these.)

- `csvtools.pl` (distributed with the obsolete [`csvtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvtools) package).
- `makeglos.pl` (distributed with the obsolete [`glossary`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossary) package).
- `makejmlrbook` (distributed with [`jmlr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/jmlr)). This no longer conforms to PMLR (formerly JMLR W&CP) guidelines. Production editors should use the newer [`makejmlrbookgui`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/makejmlrbookgui/) instead.

Comment: There were another few Biber warnings in version 2.7 that are only fixed in 2.8 (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395654/35864)

Comment: @moewe Thanks, updated.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good idea, added not fixed and deprecated sections.

Comment: Do you know `texdef` is not updated? Because Norbert said it was on 03/10 - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388721/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-protect-a-tex-live-file-from-updates-with-no-chan#comment980299_388721 - and he should know, I guess. I can't easily tell as I patched my copy - repeatedly, in fact.

Comment: @cfr The version that ships with TeX live 2017 (updated just seconds ago) does not seem to be updated. I just checked that I still get the error when calling `texdef --help`.

Comment: @moewe That's strange. `texdef --help` works fine for me with TL2017 and `texdef --version` shows `texdef: Version 1.7b -- 2012/05/15`. (I have Perl v5.18.4 installed.) However, there is a pair of unescaped `{}` (in `$_[0] =~ s/\\[{}]//g`) within subroutine `remove_invalid_braces` which might cause a problem.

Comment: @cfr Perhaps Norbert could verify. Maybe move it up to the "fixed but not yet released" section if it's still pending.

Comment: I'm using Perl `v5.26.0` on Ubuntu 17.10, `tlmgr` says `texdef` is on version 1.7b. Since you are using Perl v5.18.4 maybe 'These have been deprecated since v5.16, with a deprecation message raised for some uses starting in v5.22. Unfortunately, the code added to raise the message was buggy and failed to warn in some cases where it should have.' (from your link above) explains it.

Comment: @moewe That could be it. (Perhaps I won't upgrade Perl just yet `:-)`)

Comment: @moewe Though the warnings worked fine in the case of `texdef` - it carried on alarmingly for months and months before finally giving an error. Nicola: your `perl` is too old to break properly ;).

Comment: I got clarification from Norbert and updated the answer accordingly. Hope that is OK. Cc. @moewe

Comment: @cfr Thanks :-)

Comment: On TeXLive 2016 (boo, I know), `latexmk` complains with, e.g. `-C` option, about "File::Glob::glob() will disappear in perl 5.30. Use File::Glob::bsd_glob() instead. at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk line 3253." Dunno if it is fixed already.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I saw a recent CTAN announcement with an update for `latexmk` with a reference to glob, so it's possible it's just been fixed.