# Is it worth having a Community Wiki post for installing TeXLive directly (not package-managed) on Linux/Mac

Tags: discussion

There have been a few questions lately on problems with `tlmgr` on Linux (specifically Debian/Ubuntu) being the wrong version ("you cannot use TL2021 `tlmgr` to update TL2022" or similar).

Is it worth having one 'definitive' answer (as a Community Wiki), which we can refer people to? I can see from the [often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions) that there is a (quite old, but somewhat detailed) description of [installing TeXLive on Debian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). While this is fine for installing, it doesn't seem to cover the problems with attempting to install the latest version when there is a previous version already present. A few questions have had the problem of a previous version being there, unknown to the user, as a dependency of something else due to the package manager, and the previous version is generally the one selected by `sudo`.

I am happy to write up a question and start the answer if people think that it is a worthwhile endeavour.

Comment: This would definitely be a useful standard reference. I'd also be very interested in an authoritative answer, that `tlmgr` can't be used to update at least in user mode seems to be the reality of at least the Debian version, but I don't think that's universally true for any packaged version of TeX Live (though you would still be [stuck to that TL version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25089) if it wasn't kept up to date).

Comment: We have this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution which is quite extensive and also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107017/why-does-tex-live-require-yearly-updates.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a bad idea so just do it and let the search engine decide if it's worthy.