# How do I put (La)TeX in Markdown?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths)

Math.SE has this -- typing `$\delta(x)$` renders the LaTeX expression for me.

How do I do the same thing on this site?

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths `:)`

Comment: And maybe this one too: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/automatic-rendering-of-code-provided-in-questions-answers `:)`

Comment: You don't: we are not a mathematics site, we are a TeX one :-) Probably this question is a duplicate of the first one that @PauloCereda linked to.