# How to put drops of math text into an ocean of normal text in a tex.stackexchange question

Tags: discussion

I've just read part of the controversy about enabling TeX math markup in
tex.stackexchange questions (mostly [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths) )

The current practice of to put the math text into an image and then
put the image into the question.

My question is, what if I need to write a tex.stackexchange question that is mostly
normal text with just a few mathematical characters or small equations in it ?
I cannot create a png that is just made of a few characters and will display as
a normal snippet of text (rather than an image separated from all the rest), can I ?

I've also considered creating a big image of the whole question (compiled
with tools that do implement math markup). But that has drawbacks as well (people
will no longer be able to correct/edit part of the question).

All those thoughts came to me after somebody suggested I change my markup 
in one of my recent [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314818/merge-eight-tikz-commands-into-one-using-if?noredirect=1#comment768567_314818).
So far, none of the alternatives to the current markup of the question seems worth
the trouble to me.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need such an equation in a question or answer?

Comment: @JosephWright As you can see in the question I linked to, I need such equations because they convert some parameters into others, in the construction of a certain geometric figure in TikZ.

Comment: There's no controversy, actually. Our focus is quite clear: we aim at the source code. Besides, no rendering engine available is really TeX, it's only heavily inspired (and sometimes badly implemented).

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is... could you provide some indication (even if its pictures) of what your post would have to look like now and what you would ideally like it to look like if MathJax was enabled?

Comment: I too don't see any problems