# How to insert basic commands?

Tags: discussion, code

Could anyone give me a list of commands which could be useful for people who are new to this site?

I don't know how to insert TeX code or any other type of code or any other simple commands, such as equations.

Comment: I'm not sure what we can add over the help you can get from the 'Post a question'/'Post an answer' editor: StackExchange do cover this. You can use Markdown plus a limited amount of HTML ...

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Also, TeX code in questions does *not* render as math. This is by design. [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/2693)