# Why there is no showcasing tool for TeX?

Tags: feature-request

I've been wondering why there is no showcasing/preview tool like JSFiddle for TeX?

Also a PDF viewer would work great.

Comment: @JouleV I'm sorry if this is completely off topic. I found the feature-request tag fits well so I chose meta.

Comment: If you want to have a PDF viewer and a compiler on TeX.SE which automatically compile the files and show the output, it is impossible. Many code snippets on TeX.SE are not compilable, how can the automation deal with it? Also, updating the TeX distribution used for that would be really difficult.

Comment: My 'feature-request' is about having such PDF viewer on the main site. Like StackOverflow has the 'include snippet' feature.

Comment: If that is code formatting, we also have that feature. If that is a PDF viewer, I think I _strongly_ prefer a _good_ screenshot which only include the necessary parts and possibly some custom marks.

Comment: Just let me clarify: A field where you put the TeX code, a window that shows the generated output of this TeX code. Like an online TeX editor but fully integrated into the main site. But I understand why this would be hard to realize.

Comment: Then read my first comment. In short: it is nearly impossible IMHO.

Comment: There are some online LaTeX compilers. From fully-fledged systems like Overleaf and Verbosus to smaller systems that only produce a PDF to equation compilers. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/35864. Maybe not exactly what you had in mind, but some tools are out there.

Comment: Reasonably related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/86

Answer (score 4):

There is [texlive.js](https://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/), which is pdfTeX from TeX Live 2012 [transpiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) to JavaScript using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/).
[One of the forks](https://fzimmermann89.github.io/texlive.js/) has been updated to use pdfTeX from TeX Live 2016.