# NewCommand LaTeX on This Site

Tags: discussion

I would like to post a question on this site (or mathoverflow mathstackexchange) such that it uses a new command.

For example, if I just type:

```
\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\left ( #1 \right )}
\newcommand{\curly}[1]{\left \{ #1 \right \} }
\newcommand{\squared}[1]{\left [ #1 \right ]}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

Some math equations are:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    & \tab[0.4cm] \iota_{\theta} = \mathbb{E}_{\theta} \squared{\dot{l_{\theta}}^2} 
    = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bracket{4 \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^3}^2 C \exp{- \sum_{i=1}^d (x_i-\theta)^4} dx
    \\ & = 16 C \curly{\sum_{i=1}^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i^6 \exp{- \sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4}  dx +
    2 \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i^3x_j^3 \exp{- \sum_{i=1}^d x_i^4}  dx }
    \\ & = 16 C d \bracket{\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{d-1} \frac{3}{8} \Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}
    = 12d \bracket{\Gamma \bracket{\frac{1}{4}}}^{-1}\Gamma \bracket{\frac{3}{4}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

It is not going to implement my new commands on this site. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: MathJaX is not enabled on this site, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/86 for more on why this is so.

Comment: Once you delete the * from `\hspace*`, this works fine on Math.SE, which does enable MathJax.  I assume MathOverflow would be similar.  But I have to caution you: "I would like to post a question on this site (or mathoverflow mathstackexchange)" is a big red flag.  Those three sites have almost no overlap (just a bit between Math.SE and MO).  Make sure you know the intended audience of the question.