# Formatting Sand-Box

Tags: support, markdown, sandbox, formatting

As per the SO question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) (if you want to know how they did something there, take a look at the source, as per the hack documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/view-source-link-on-all-questions)), I suggest that this (CW) question be used for testing purposes. Feel free to edit this question, add answers, experiment with deletion or markdown or what-have you.

Use this [Markdown Editing Help reference](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) as a guide, or [this tome](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) if you want to know every detail.

I'll take this question down if the community thinks that it is inappropriate, but if it is appropriate, we could have something like it pointed to in the FAQ and in the markdown manual.

Comment: Not a duplicate of this [LaTeX sandbox proposal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158/latex-sand-box)

Comment: See [this page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/) for information on comment markup.

Comment: Has nothing to do with LaTeX sandbox porposal...but if this is confusing I'll edit to make it clear.

Comment: Testing backslashes in comments: ``\`` ~ <bt><bt>\<bt><bt>; ``\\`` ~ <bt>bt>\\<bt><bt>; ``\ `` ~ <bt><bt>\ <bt><bt>. Here <bt>=`.

Comment: @Werner -- i think one of those bracketed `bt`s has a left angle missing.  (thanks for the pointer.)

Comment: Single quote comment (with leading spaces): `    code`

Comment: Double quote comment (with leading spaces): ``    code``

Answer (score 7):

Typesetting backslashes, backticks and spaces:

1. 
2. \
3. `\`
4. `\\`
5. `\`
6. `
7. ``
8. `` ` ``
9. ``` ``
10. ``` `` ```
11. ``` `
12. `` \` ``
13. `` \` ``
14. 

Use HTML formatting mixed with markdown for spaces.

````
1. &nbsp;
2. \\
3. `\`
4. `\\`
5. <code>\&nbsp;</code>
6. `
7. ``
8. <code>`</code>
9. ``` ``
10. <code>``</code>
11. ``` `
12. <code>\\`</code>
13. ``\` ``
14. <code>&nbsp;</code>
````

Link testing:

- Question: [Formatting Sand-Box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/208/5764)
- Answer: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3150/5764
- Another question: [How to end the "unanswered" status of really solved questions in the comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3640/5764)
- Another answer: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3641/5764

---

Taken from [In comments - how do I highlight with back-ticks when the last character is a backslash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231901/168244):

Here are the rules for inline code in posts and comments.

**POSTS**: If you want backticks inside an inline code snippet, surround them with any amount of backticks not used in the code. Examples:

- ``` ``this is a `backtick` thing`` ``` renders as `` this is a `backtick` thing ``
- ````` ````here are one ` two `` three ``` backticks```` ````` renders as ```` here are one ` two `` three ``` backticks ````
- Use spaces if backticks are at beginning or end - ``` `` $` `` ``` renders as `` $` ``
- `` `testing testing\`123`testing` `` renders as `testing testing\`123`testing`

**COMMENTS**: Simply use `\` to escape backticks. Limitation: you can't escape backslashes, so you can't have a backslash at the end of an inline code snippet. Also, `` `test`123`test` `` doesn't work.

- `` `this is a \`backtick\` thing` `` renders as  `` this is a `backtick` thing ``
- etc.
- `` `testing testing\ `123 `testing` `` renders as `testing testing\` 123 `testing`

Comment: `[meta]`: [meta]; `[main]`: [main]; `[about]`: [about]; `[help]`: [help]

Comment: `[About TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange][about]`: [About TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange][about]

Comment: `[meta.tex.se]`: [meta.tex.se]; `[tex.se]`: [tex.se]

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer which can be used as sandbox answer. Feel free to edit if you wish to try markdown. Below the line would be good. So, the question doesn't remain unanswered.

---

Here's a funny formatting trap: code after a list item doesn't format: [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/2693)  The solution is to insert an HTML comment  between the list item and the code:

- A list item

  \begin{document}
- Another list item with `<!>` after it and some following code: (needs to be separated by blank lines):

```
\begin{document}
```

Perl?

```
sub run_command (@) {
    my $origcmdline = join(" ", grep {defined} @_);
    return if $origcmdline eq "";

    my $cmdline = $origcmdline;
```

description lists

\predisplaypenalty

penalty for page break just before a display

doesn't look very promising in preview…

TEX

Hm, would've been nice

- A list
- ```
    Some code
  ```

(See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides...).)

*Bla bla* bla*.*
*Bla bla* bla_._
*Bla bla* bla*.*

The text is from [http://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Αθήνα](http://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1) foo

Comment: @morbusg: Interesting, description lists should work according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites.

Comment: @doncherry They do, at least the HTML tags show up in the source code. However, as there is no CSS to format them, the result is not very pretty. See also the feature request [Better style for HTML 'definition list' <dl> elements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22972/better-style-for-html-definition-list-dl-elements) on meta.SO.

Comment: <code>\\</code>

Comment: ``\``, ``\\``...

Comment: With this setup, does the font for regular text come from the `charter` package or `mathdesign`? Switching the order of `\usepackage{charter}` and `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` produces different outputs. Also, the latter setup complains about `Font shape T1/bch/m/fsc undefined(Font)` .. (small caps?)

Answer (score 5):

Just testing some entities:

`&#211hello;` in the preview produces Óhello;  What happens in the main?

&#211hello;

Strike <strike>out</strike> works.

Comment: does this work `\\ ` more text?

Comment: this should work `\\​` ...

Answer (score 4):

Shrt nswrs r k.​​​

Comment: cmmnt[.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Trying to see if I can put in `<` and `>`:

```
$1 > 2$ while $2 < 3$.  \\
Seems to be OK with new stuff.
```

---

Code inside list is indented by more space (twice more than the usual):

**Code**:

```
This is code because four spaces go before me.
```

- This is a bullet!

  I am not code even though there are four spaces before me. But, if eight spaces precede me, I'll be one.

  ```
  Like this.
  ```

Answer (score 2):

1. a list

   1. with stuff
2. in it

Answer (score 1):

Testing link prettification for `https` URLs:
[Formatting Sand-Box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/208/21344)

Testing link prettification for `http` URLs:
[Formatting Sand-Box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/208/21344)

Testing link prettification for protocol-less URLs:
//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/208/21344

Answer (score 0):

Just a sandbox post, please ignore.

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

The code iterates through different combinations of jot, baselineskip, lineskip, and create a normal `gather` environment and a `array` environment. Then for each item use `zref-savepos` to measure the vertical distance between the 2 lines, then report the result.

Replace `\pretty` with `\tl_show` if you want. (will print the log on the terminal)

[image: rendered document]

The log: (there are 2 wrong entries unfortunately...)

[image: result log]

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{prettytok}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\errorcontextlines=100
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\def \__index {0}
\clist_map_variable:nNn {
 0sp/0sp/0sp,
 0sp/0sp/5sp,
 0sp/5sp/0sp,
 0sp/5sp/5sp,
 5sp/0sp/0sp,
 5sp/0sp/5sp,
 5sp/5sp/0sp,
 5sp/5sp/5sp,
 0sp/0sp/1cm,
 0sp/1.1cm/0sp,
 0sp/1.1cm/1cm,
 1.2cm/0sp/0sp,
 1.2cm/0sp/1cm,
 1.2cm/1.1cm/0sp,
 1.2cm/1.1cm/1cm
 } \__a {
 

 \edef\__index{\int_eval:n {\__index+1}}

 \def \__match #1/#2/#3/ {
  \def\jot{#1}
  \baselineskip=#2\relax
  \lineskip=#3\relax
 }
 \expandafter \__match \__a/



 
\begingroup

%\savebox\strutbox {}

\begin{gather*}
 a=b \zsavepos{a\__index} \\
 \dfrac22 \zsavepos{b\__index}
\end{gather*}

\endgroup

\dim_compare:nNnTF {\baselineskip} = {0sp} {
 \edef\customskip{\dim_to_decimal_in_sp:n{\dimexpr\lineskip+\jot\relax} sp}
} {
\let\customskip\jot
}
\[
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
 %\baselineskip=\baselineskipx\relax
 \edef\oldbaselineskip{\the\baselineskip}
 \edef\oldlineskip{\the\lineskip}
 \begin{array}{c}
  %\baselineskip=\normalbaselineskip
  a=b      \zsavepos{c\__index} \copy\strutbox \rule[\dimexpr-0.3\dimexpr\oldbaselineskip\relax\relax]{0pt}{\dimexpr\oldbaselineskip\relax} \\[0pt] \\[\customskip] \\[0pt]
  \dfrac22 \zsavepos{d\__index} \copy\strutbox \rule[\dimexpr-0.3\dimexpr\oldbaselineskip\relax\relax]{0pt}{\dimexpr\oldbaselineskip\relax}
 \end{array}
\]



\pretty:x{
 case~\__index.~
 \int_eval:n{\zposy{a\__index} - \zposy{b\__index}}sp
 =
 \int_eval:n{\zposy{c\__index} - \zposy{d\__index}}sp
}


\int_compare:nNnTF 
 {\zposy{a\__index} - \zposy{b\__index}}
 =
 {\zposy{c\__index} - \zposy{d\__index}}
 {
 }
 {
  \pretty:n{ERROR!}
 }

}

\ExplSyntaxOff







\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made this [JSFiddle script](https://jsfiddle.net/juanmf/Lz7nycxm/latest/) for basic markup + latex editing / printing.

Allows to:

- Copy-paste src (original, markup with rendered math, html with rendered math) to a math question.
- Print rendered HTML.

** EDIT:
Just found out about https://hackmd.io/ which does a very good job for latex sandbox and more.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SycmW.png