# Why do code snippets not work after lists?

Tags: support, code, lists

I want to insert a code snippet after a list but the code snippet is not a part of the list item.

1. This is the first item.
2. This is the second item

   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
   \end{document}

Should I always insert a rule to make it work?

1. This is the first item.
2. This is the second item

A dummy rule is added to fix this problem.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The same issue happened in StackOverflow. I have just checked it.

Comment: See [this answer on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could insert a piece of invisible HTML code:

```
 1. This is the first item.
 2. This is the second item

<!-- code follows -->

    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \end{document}
```

Output:

> 1. This is the first item.
> 2. This is the second item
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \begin{document}
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: I see that this issue is here for about 4 years and it still here, is there anyone working on it? (by the way your answer works good)