# Code following a list doesn’t work

Tags: bug, code, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/why-does-code-snippet-after-list-not-work-again)

If I add code listings directly after a list it doesn’t work, I guess this is a bug … cause if theres some other text between it works fine.

**Example**

- some text
- of a list

  \documentclass{minimal}

  \begin{document}
    Some code
  \end{document}
- another list
- with some text

and some code

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
  Some code
\end{document}
```

Comment: You simply need to add a HTML comment `<!-- -->` before the code, as shown in the answer of the duplicate question. See also Hendrik's comment with the link to Meta.SX. I assume that issue has to do with the handling of indention in lists.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Sorry for overlooking the duplicate and thanks for the answer!