# How to move a block of code by 4 spaces

Tags: support, markdown, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks)

What is the shortcut for spacing a block of code, picked from some TeX editor, so that they are spaced four spaces? (as opposed to moving each line by four spaces)

Comment: Highlight the block of code and press the `{}` button (or CTRL+K).

Comment: If highlighting a lengthy block of code is too cumbersome for you, then you should support me by upvoting [the following proposoal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133507/186526).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can highlight the block of code and press the `{}` button or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

[image]

Note that code formatting requires additional formatting when used in conjunction with a list. For more on this, see

- [Is there a problem with code formatting?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2529/5764)
- [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/5764)

In short,

- Insert an additional 4 spaces for each level inside the list that you want the code to be represented at;
- Insert an HTML comment `<!-- -->` (or similar) to break the list-code structure.

For a general discussion on code in posts, see [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192/5764)