# Code formatting after itemize only with some text?

Tags: support, code, formatting, lists

why is code formatting in answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169741/5328 disabled when I remove the period between itemization and the code?

**Edit:** I changed the answer by inserting a HTML comment as suggested, so now all is properly formatted. However, the link above is now a bit useless. Thanks to all answerers and commentators, to describe the initial problem again and for their support.

Comment: The Markdown is seeing the code as part of the list, so you'd need two indents (8 spaces) to make this work. Not sure if that's a bug or not!

Comment: If the code is part of the list you need 8 spaces, if not you could add an HTML comment after the list as in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/why-do-code-snippets-not-work-after-lists?rq=1

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I believe that this is the correct answer ;)

Comment: @tohecz I don't know, but I added an answer anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

References:

- [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)
- [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/why-do-code-snippets-not-work-after-lists?rq=1)

This is because any indented text immediately following a list is seen as part of the list, as Joseph mentions. Hence, if you have

```
* list item

   some text

some more text
```

this is printed as

> - list item
>
>   some text
>
> some more text

As mentioned in the first question referenced above, this is basically a limitation in the Markdown format, nothing to do about it.

There are two ways of dealing with this, depending on what your intention is:

1. If the code is part of the list, indent it with *eight* spaces instead of four.
2. If the code is not part of the list, but follows after it, add something between the two, such as an HTML comment, i.e.

   ```
    <!--  -->
   ```

A tip for indenting blocks with eight spaces: Select the block and hit the `{}` button/Ctrl+K to indent with four spaces. Then write a single character (such as your period) on the line just before the block, select both this and the entire block, then hit the `{}` button again. Finally, delete the single character.