# Add preview of comment formatting

Tags: feature-request

As a novice user, I would find it extremely helpful if there was a preview of the comment field. To clarify, I believe it would help format comments in a more legible way.

Comment: This has been asked on the main meta, I think, and 'STATUS DECLINED' by the site developers

Comment: @JosephWright You [are right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/preview-for-comments).

Comment: You can make edits for 5 minutes. Also you can get help with clicking on this word on the right of the comment field.

Comment: Bummer - I think the pros forget how overwhelming all of this can be to someone new to the system (even if you have a "technical" background). I'm enamoured with the efficiency and thoughtful design of these communities, but have also been frustrated time and again by the challenges of _getting_ the help I'm looking for. 

Thanks for letting me know it's been addressed elsewhere (unfortunately I cannot weigh-in on that discussion for lack of meta-meta-reputation! :S).

Answer (score 2):

The inline formatting is supposed to work the same way in posts as in comments. Therefore you can try it with the instant preview of the posts, in the cases where you are not sure about it.

*(Or, just comment a bit more, you'll soon learn it `;)` )*

Related: [Typesetting backslashes, backticks and spaces in *Formatting Sand-Box*](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3150/11002)

Comment: _supposed to_ \neq _does_! e.g. I have no idea how you managed the skipped line in your comment. After accidentally posting twice by trying _enter / return_ (as one would in posts), I  then, while stressin' about the 5min edit limit (& still trying to be thoughtful and clear in my comment), succeeded in skipping a line using _shift + return_ (something foreign to me until I joined this community) only to find that the line-skip was elided in the comment when posted! Granted, not the epic struggle of a lifetime, still it is an unnecessary barrier to full participation in the community.