# Is it possible to write draft post on TEX.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to write draft posts on TEX.SE? It could be useful when you are interrupted and you don't have the time to finish your question/answer. In such cases, AFAIK, I don't think it is possible today to save the draft and finish later. (?)

Comment: The draft you write in the big white text boxes is saved every something-ty seconds or so on the server and will be shown again if you revisit the answer or question. [It’s 45 seconds.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238)

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice. I would be glad to accept this as an answer if you convert it.

Comment: Yes, please turn that into an answer so I can downvote it.  This feature of the AJAX is not something I would rely on to save my work.  In particular, I don't think it's suitable for "save the draft and finish later".  More just to make browser back/forward actions work sensibly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel (what a name!) And it allows to save only one draft. What when you have two or more question in mind?

Comment: In addition to Ben: It already happened to me, that a draft disappeared without interaction by me, I suppose an unwanted cookie delete on my machine. But funnily it must have been artificial intelligence: I later realized, that my answer would have been wrong. :-)

Comment: @Speravir It's the spirit of the machine. SE.TeX does not like draft of false answer :-)

Comment: @ppr Yes, seems so …

Answer (score 6):

Technically, you're allowed to [try whatever you want in the Sand-Box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box). The formatting mark-down for questions and for answers is the same, therefore you can make your draft an answer in the sand-box. Just start it with something like:

> This is a draft of a question for the main site, I'll use and remove it before December 25, 2013.

This should be IMHO fine. It's good to add the date there, and it's good to delete it once you don't need it anymore.

*However, I'd like to know a moderator's opinion on my suggestion before you use it.*

Comment: ok but it's still a workaround and not a proper draft management system.

Answer (score 2):

The author of a post (question or answer) can undelete his own post, as long as he closed it himself.  If the community or a moderator voted to close/delete, then they will have to agree to undeletion.

Also, deleted posts don't show up in one's user profile, so it's necessary to save the URL to continue editing.

Still, this is an option for saving multiple drafts that aren't yet ready for public viewing.

Comment: However, on some sites (not here), doing this can lead to getting question-banned, which is a bot-based ban and can't be manually overwritten by the mods, only the higher powers can do that.