# Raw https links are prettified in the actual post, but not in the preview

Tags: bug, user-interface, hyperlinks

When editing [another user's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232958/21344), I noticed that raw `https` links to locations on the SE Network are not prettified in the previewer in the same way `http` links are.

When actually submitting the change and viewing the live post, the links (both `https` and `http`) *are* prettified as expected. So the problem seems to be limited to the previewer.

I see this behavior using Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m on Windows 7, with and without all userscripts disabled. Several users have confirmed the behavior on different browsers in the comments. I have posted [an answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6010/21344) at the [Formatting Sand-Box](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/208/21344) for others to test on different browsers/platforms, if desired.

Comment: Confirmed with a very *not up-to-date* `Mozilla Firefox 26.0`

Comment: Confirmed with Firefox 36.0.

Comment: Thank you both for testing. :-)

Comment: Related: [https links to same site don't auto-prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218060/168244)

Comment: Good find @Werner, perhaps the fix was applied to the code for posts but not to the previewer.

Comment: Still an open bug, today. Seems to by SE-wide.

Comment: @mhchem indeed... good thing I have not been holding my breath! ;-)