# The Unofficial TeX-SX FAQ

Tags: support, faq

Welcome to tex.stackexchange.com (otherwise known as TeX-SX or TeX-SE).  This is the *unofficial FAQ* which we've put together to help you figure out how to make best use of this site.

There is an *official* FAQ, linked at the top of every page, but that one is fairly general as it (mostly) applies to all of the sites on the [StackExchange](http://www.stackexchange.com) network.  Although there is much that is the same across the various sites, each is also home to its own community and each therefore has its own quirks and characteristics that are useful to know about (whether or not you are familiar with other of the StackExchange sites).

What follows is a list of questions, answers, and other posts organised by topic that we, the more experienced users of this site, think would be useful for people to know.  As is standard on FAQs, if there's something you'd like to know that isn't here, [just ask](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

### What should I know *before* asking a question?

1. [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

### "How do I ..." questions

1. [When writing a comment, how do I ensure that the person it is addressed to gets notified?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598)
2. [How do I mark inline code?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863)
3. [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)
4. [General formatting help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
5. [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117)
6. [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)
7. [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2136)

### "Something weird just happened" questions

1. [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445)
2. [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340)
3. [Which questions should be marked 'Community Wiki'? Which ones should just be closed?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/219)
4. [SO versus MO model (possible FAQ entry)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/197)
5. [My question was closed as a duplicate, but I still need help. What can I do?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1015)
6. [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272)

### What should I bear in mind when writing an answer?

1. [Quality Standards for Answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227)

### How do comments work?

1. [When writing a comment, how do I ensure that the person it is addressed to gets notified?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598)

### How else can I contribute to this fanTeXstic site?

1. [Things to do on a slow day at TeX-SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/385)
2. You Can Edit Other People's Stuff:

   - [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340)
3. You can clean up some tags:

   - [Our set of tags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302)

   For specifics on some of the above tagging guidelines, see

   - [About meta-tagging](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/294)
   - [FAQ request: encourage use of [big-list] meta-tag](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336)
   - [What to do with the 'latex' tag?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/365)

### Other resources

1. [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) (on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com))
2. [New user asking for TeX.SX usage tips and tricks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976)

Comment: To keep this entry clean, please discuss it on the question: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1145/86