# How do I mark code blocks?

Tags: support, faq, markdown, code, syntax-highlighting

How do I mark code blocks, and how do I adjust syntax highlighting? Can I emphasize pieces of my code block? And how do code blocks in lists and blockquotes work?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The simplest way is to indent your code block by 4 spaces: To get the output

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize]{scrbook}
```

just type

```
    \documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize]{scrbook}
```

(The *first* empty line is essential, the last one is recommended.)
If you have more than one line, then it's simpler to highlight the code block and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (or click the "code" button, with "{}" on it). This auto-indents the highlighted code by 4 spaces (and also adds the empty lines in the beginning and in the end).

[image]

*See below for code blocks in lists and blockquotes.*

### Syntax highlighting

By default, your code gets some LaTeX syntax highlighting. (This doesn't work on meta.tex.sx, so unfortunately you can't see it here.) If you *don't* want this syntax highlighting, you can use a special HTML comment to specify the language. For *no highlighting*, use

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    (J:\MiKTeX2.9\tex\latex\elsarticle\elsarticle.cls
    Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
```

(You wouldn't want `\MiKTeX` to be highlighted as a control sequence, right?) Note that the HTML comment must *not* be indented, and that the blank line between the `<!-- language: ... -->` and the indented code block is *required*. For a list of supported languages have a look here: [Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971).

### Emphasizing pieces of the code

If you want to highlight parts of your code using **bold** or *slanted* text, or if you want to <s>strike something out</s>, you have to use the HTML `<pre>` tag instead of 4 space indentation. For example,

```
<pre>
\documentclass[paper=a5,<i>pagesize</i>]{scrbook}
\usepackage<b>[draft]</b>{graphicx}
</pre>
```

gives

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

(Note that the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags [should be on separate lines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84290/can-the-pre-tag-start-in-a-new-line-possible-previewer-bug/99600#99600), without indentation.)
For striking something out, use `<s>...</s>`.
Using just `<pre>` you don't get syntax highlighting, so you can use this as an alternative to `<!-- language: lang-none -->`. Be careful, however, to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` if you want `<` and `>` in `<pre>` blocks; you may also need `&amp;` for `&`.

If you want syntax highlighting *and* additional emphasis in **bold** or *slanted*, use `<code>` inside the `<pre>` block:

```
<pre>
<code>\documentclass[paper=a5,<i>pagesize</i>]{scrbook}
\usepackage<b>[draft]</b>{graphicx}</code>
</pre>
```

Note that there are no line breaks after `<code>` and before `</code>`; otherwise the code block would start and end with an empty line (as the second code block in this very answer).

### Code blocks in lists

If your code appears inside a list, you must indent a *further four spaces* for every level of nesting. An example:

```
1. The first point I want to make

        This is the code

1. The second point I want to make
```

gives

1. The first point I want to make

   ```
    This is the code
   ```
2. The second point I want to make

So you need 8 spaces in the first level, 12 spaces in the second level and so on.

### Code blocks after lists

If you want a code block immediately *after* a list, you [need to put an HTML comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637) between the list and the code block:

```
1. This is part of a list

<!-- an HTML comment -->

    This is the code
```

gives

1. This is part of a list

```
This is the code
```

### Code blocks in blockquotes

A blockquote is started with `>` , and a code block with 4 spaces, so for a code block within a blockquote you need *5* spaces after the `>`. An example:

```
> This is (not) a quote from the TeXbook, and here's some code:

>     \relax
```

gives

> This is (not) a quote from the TeXbook, and here's some code:
>
> ```
> \relax
> ```

Comment: @TH: Oh my, thanks for the correction. I managed to delete the spaces in one of the edits. Probably I was confused by the nasty preview.

Comment: Any idea why the preview is so horrible for this post?

Comment: @TH: [Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84290/can-the-pre-tag-start-in-a-new-line-possible-previewer-bug). But there's no satisfactory answer yet. Probably I'll remove the line break before `</pre>` and maybe even mention the problem in the post here, but first I'll wait some more time for an answer.

Comment: Ah. Okay.

Comment: @TH: Tim Stone [just gave an excellent explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84290/can-the-pre-tag-start-in-a-new-line-possible-previewer-bug/99600#99600). (I see you're still [located in Changdad](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1287/1235) :-))

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. As for Changdad, it's close enough to "here" for me. This is the Internet, no need for [meatspace coordinates](http://sethjust.com/2011/07/11/sign-your-email-like-randall-waterhouse/).