# An simple example - typesetting here

Tags: discussion, typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks)

I'm new user here and my English is poor. So when I was putting one question here, a person told me that I needed to use some codes to show better my doubts. How should I write the code here for it to appear this way?
[image]

Unfortunately I am writing and putting this way: bla-bla-bla

\documentclass[notes=show,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow} etc, ....

because I did't understand yet the help and the correct way. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you indent your code with four spaces, it will appear as code in your question.

Comment: This is really off-topic since it does not ask a question about TeX. You can learn some markdown tricks used in this site in http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: We usually discuss this type of issues on the http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com . A moderator would probably move this question to there.

Comment: This question is very similar to [How do I mark code blocks?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: I really tried to understand the page of help, but I could't yet. A simple figure would be very helpful for me. Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: @Moura The simplest way is to add four spaces at the beginning of every line of code. Instead, you could also highlight all code lines and hit Ctrl+K (or click the "code" button, with "{}" on it). This auto-indents the highlighted code by 4 spaces. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: I think that I finally managed to understand. Is it necessary to put the commands <pre><code> tex commands ....
</code></pre> ?

Comment: @Moura: No, you  don't have to insert those tags. Just put four spaces at the start of every code line, or mark the whole code block and press Ctrl+K

Comment: It's very simple and now I undestood. I'm laughing until now. Thank you doncherry and Jake. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood how I should proceed to put the command's tex in a question. As explained to me by Jake and doncherry, we need to select the command's tex code block and then press Ctrl+K. Another command is too simple: press the button {} above, as explained too by doncherry.