# How to attach a tex.file to this message?

Tags: discussion

my first question is extremely silly...
how can I attach a tex file to the messages here, to give an example ?
in the bar above I see many ikons ( bold ,slanted  link etc. ) but no "append".
I tag "lualatex" because my next questions will be about it.

Many thanks!

Comment: you can't attach tex files, you must copy & paste the content (as code).

Comment: Many thanks, so i'll use code.  Sorry for such a trivial question... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't attach a file to a post. Instead, insert code directly into posts and mark them as code following the direction in [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192/5764) or the wider Stack Exchange FAQ [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/168244)

If your code chunk is too big to fit within the post (too many characters), consider reducing it down so it only highlights the problem. By doing this you may even find out the source of the problem yourself and be able to correct it! For more on how to trim your code down for a question, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)