# Procedure on refining an initial broad question. Should I replace it with multiple focused questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

users,
I asked a question on [controlling individual layers in a diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65096/how-to-make-a-diagram-composed-of-superimposed-layers-where-the-viewer-can-make) and with a bit more knowledge and help from the answers I can see the question was too broad.
I suspect that the method you use produce the diagram will probably depend on whether you want the diagram for a presentation (the beamer answer is appropriate) or an ebook (the answer for animate is probably better, along the lines of [my first attempt at this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59798/adding-tikzpicture-layers-that-can-be-viewed-sequentially-in-the-output-motzkin/59935#59935)) or even on the web (a problem for another time).

My thought is that I should ask a particular question for each of the particular end points, then maybe a person of status can move/duplicate the answers to their rightful contexts.

I've looked at this meta question on [asking a follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how)
but I'm not sure if it endorses what I think I should do in this particular case. I hope that with some help I can make the discussion around my question easy to find and use for particular queries.

Comment: Unless you have  specifically different questions about either of the particular answers you got on the original question, I would simply add to your question saying you're interested in both `beamer` and `ebook` solutions, and tag the question appropriately, but otherwise leave it as it is.

Comment: @AlanMunn, Ok, I was just concerned that I if I can have only one accepted answer then this may not be the one that is best for all applications. I will edit my question along the lines you describe.

Comment: The accepted answer is the one that helped you the most, not an indication of the "best" answer.  In this case, since you found the `beamer` solution most helpful, you can accept that answer, but the other answer has plenty of votes and is just as likely to be useful to others. And your comments about the differences are helpful too.