# Where should we pose a question? Tex-Latex + Meta-Tex + Stack Overflow

Tags: support, new-users, stackexchange

I am a new user and my [first question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/new-users-how-to-do-good-questions-and-answers) was migrated to this site of [Meta - Tex](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/). I didn't yet understand how do we have to pose questions with these different type of sites:

- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/),
- [Meta - Tex](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/),
- [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/),
- [Stack Overflow](http://stackexchange.com/)

Can someone provide a summary with:

1. aim of site
2. type of questions that can be made.

Or alternatively links that already provide information about this.

Comment: Your first Q was about [asking questions on tex.sx for new users](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) belongs to meta.tex.sx, hence community would have migrated. 1. `aim of site`: http://stackexchange.com/about (model is somewhat similar for all its sites). 2.`type of questions that can be made`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic 3.Full info at about tour page http://tex.stackexchange.com/about. I hope you gone through the comments/answers for your Q http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/new-users-how-to-do-good-questions-and-answers/3933#3933, since its related

Comment: I think there is a significant gap between new-users and regular users of `TeX`. What you take for granted is not for new users. I also believe that this information asymmetry lead to a lot of unnecessary work. In my opinion, if we can reduce this initial gap is a win-win situation to both users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [About](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about) should cover this, but for the avoidance of doubt:

1. TeX StackExchange (TeX-sx) is for questions about TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt and related topics
2. [Meta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) TeX-sx is for questions about TeX-sx itself
3. [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) is for questions about the StackExchange network, as well as questions specific to StackOverflow
4. [StackOverflow](http://stackexchange.com/about) is a general site focussed on programming, from which many spin-out sites have grown, including TeX-sx

As you've already found, it's possible for a question to be migrated from one of the sites to another. Thus for example TeX questions posted to StackOverflow tend to be migrated to TeX-sx as they are not 'general programming' (often having a more typesetting-related output), and as Tex-sx exists as a 'better' place to get TeX answers.

Comment: Meta TeX.sx is also reflexive, that is, you can ask meta questions on Meta. `:)` Personally, it would be funnier to have a `meta.meta.tex` for questions about Meta, and `meta.meta.meta.tex` about questions on the Meta site about the Meta TeX.sx, and so on. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Or we make a general `meta^n.tex` site where `n` can be variable ;-)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: `:)`

Comment: @JosephWright: I understand now that there are different help centers, although I was thinking that there only one general help. If you please can edit the answer with the following links of type of questions that can be made I would be grateful. [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about), [Meta TeX-sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) and [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Thanks