# How can I know whether an answer is obsolete?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

While I was looking for some information, I found [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134980/multiple-paragraphs-in-a-multirow-cell) about the exact problem I'm having. Unfortunately, the provided solution requires manually spacing row heights. And I'm a bit unsatisfied with this.

Now, I'm not complaining about the answer. It's a perfectly valid solution! But it's 3 years old. I was hoping that a better solution might be available today.

How would I go about this? I dropped a comment there, but it doesn't seem that this adds any visibility to the question. Considering it was posted 3 years ago, I think my chances of getting an answer (possibly new) are pretty slim.

Is it OK to open new question in this case?

Comment: Well, one 'dirty' trick is to edit the question (in an appropiate manner) such that it bumps to the front and others will be notified of it. Or provide a bounty. Asking a new question 'just' because you're a little bit unsatisfied will probably cause quick closing, unless you can provide a new aspect or a reason why the issue in  other question might not entirely be the exact problem you're facing

Comment: 3 years for TeX is almost yesterday. For tables in particular, 5 minutes ago-ish.

Comment: in general you can't know although for that question any answer that suggests using `\\ ` with or without an optional argument to denote a paragraph break should be treated with some caution.

Comment: I added another answer:-)

Answer (score 26):

Typical procedures include the following sequence of elevated proposals:

1. Comment on the answer, requesting some feedback on your updated request/criteria.
2. Visit the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) and see if one of the local experts have time on hand to look into modifying the existing (or creating an altogether new and awesome) solution.
3. Spend some of that well-earned reputation on issuing a [bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). There's nothing like reputation that stirs the creative juices of the community.
4. [Ask a follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) that references the old question, why your question is different *and* that current the solution doesn't suit your needs. Yes, the question should clearly state how it's different from the original, otherwise it could be considered a duplicate.

Leave some time between elevating your requests to make sure you've given individuals or the community enough time to respond, if anything.