# Template for (some) questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

Use case:

Joe TeXer comes to TL&Co and asks:

> Why doesn't feature X work on my computer? I've been trying to do this for hours, and my thesis is due tomorrow! Help!!!1!1!1!!!1111one

And, of course, to give adequate suggestions, we need more information, namely:

- TeX distribution used
- Packages loaded
- Operating system
- [Minimal, complete example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)
- ...

It would save a lot of time both of the users and the submitter, if the submitter is asked to supply this information in advance (because for non-trivial problems people will ask for clarification anyway). Hence, the request:

**Can we have some sort of template for questions of the type "Why doesn't X work?"**

Alternatively, this could find place in the FAQ as well. Let's be realistic though, people will most likely first ask a question, and then, possibly, browse the FAQ.

I have absolutely no idea how this could be implemented in practice, or whether it's even a viable option, but perhaps somebody could shed some light on this.

Comment: I think that for most questions, providing a minimal complete example is probably more than enough. TeX distribution, package versions, and operating system are rarely the cause of the problem (and if they are they can be quickly detected by a *minimal* example too). But I don't know if people have other suggestions?

Comment: related on how/way to ask http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/750/15717

Comment: -1 (meta-vote) for the reasons @JuanA.Navarro mentioned, and also I’d be worried that we’d “scare off” new users. People don’t want too much formalized stuff like that, and SE is already asking more than your average forum with the tags and the built-in filters for quality and duplicates.

Comment: @doncherry i agree this forum is high quality and excellently maintained, it was just a blank idea on papers. I am not forcing anyone.It was just for record here. I really respect all for enduring effort to keep high quality standards. I don't want to be knitpicking also. Hope you understand me. I don't think no vote is enough instead of a downvote.

Comment: How can a `MWE` "reflect/solve" the `OS/TeXdistro/Updated based problems` unless the OP posts his `OS/TeXdistro/Updated info` or post his `.log`. May be we need to wait another 1day/1hr for a comment from OP after our request for info even before its closed or remain unanswered due to interest lost from current commentator. It's `Channelising` the simple info on OP's question .

Comment: Hi Mr/Mrs Downvoter, I feel its worthwhile to leave a comment if it deserves a downvote. Please post your feedback. This is meta Q&A , its on papers not a finalised one.

Answer (score 2):

Idea to Customize "Ask question" in TeX.SX by OP.

**1.** Is it possible to include OP question template as asked by Martin Tapankov like

- **OS**: ?, -- asking `.log` is another alternative* or `mandatory tags`
- **TeXdistro**:? -- asking `.log` is another alternative* or `mandatory tags`
- **All updated**: ? -- asking `.log` is another alternative* (already mentioned in [FAQ section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq))

**2. (if we can have a right place to paste/host it without increasing the question size, may be suggest dropbox, paste.ubuntu.com etc..)**

**For example:** a first line of `.log` file give idea about `OS`,`TeXdistro` and `when updated/pdftex engine update status`

**TeX Live on Linux**

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=pdflatex 2013.3.21)`

**TeX Live on Windows**

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2013.3.22)`

**MiKTeX on Windows**

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2012.6.26)`

**Implications:** If its implemented, A single liner comment may be enough to resolve Q&A, which would speed-up and improve productivity. Thereby less unanswered Q&A.

**Thanks to Karl's students and percusse for log file data**. Anyone can update if their .log file info is missing here.

As discussed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8565481#8565481))

Joseph Wright Reply: We don't control the editing box, that's set by the network and I think very unlikely to be customised.

Some meta references [Can/should we get a “How to Ask” page?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/750/15717) and [Proposal to Improve FAQ: Update before Asking Questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2196/15717)

Answer (score 2):

In the Community Ads question here on Meta we can see some prescribed format for the answer as the following

[image]

I think a similar structure, tailored for the question with a simple MWE structure, would fix most of our problems, asking for MWE, asking to complete the code snippet and a few more.

Comment: +1, Good template idea, may be mandatory `OS` tag and `TeXdistro` tag for some Q's or posting first line of `.log`