# Can/should we get a “How to Ask” page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Over the last few days, the list of [unanswered questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered) has grown a fair bit. Some of the questions with no satisfactory answer are about specific IDEs, so it is somewhat expected that they don't get a fast answer. But recently there also seems to be a fair amount of poorly asked questions without enough context or a clear formulation of the problem.

When new users on stackoverflow ask their first question, they are greeted with a [“How to Ask” page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) (see also [the SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/)). This might make at new user stop for a short time and think about how to formulate the question. Such a page seems to be a useful thing (though I have no idea how well it works on SO).

Should we get a similar page. If so, should the text differ from the SO text?

Comment: I was hoping that one of the SE team would stop by and tell us whether or not this was possible.  Perhaps this should be taken to meta.SO?

Comment: @Andrew: I think the SE team only looks at [tag:feature-request] questions with enough support. And this doesn't seem to be a popular idea.

Answer (score 5):

This is now fixed. On the right side of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask there appears a note on how to ask questions:

[image: "How to Ask" note on TeX.SX]

Note that when the text area for the content of the question or the field for filling in tags gets focus other notes are shown. You can get back the "How to Ask" note by refocusing the title field.

Comment: Should I [tag:status-completed] this?

Comment: @JosephWright I think so. Dunno if Caramdir agrees. I answered this question to close it since I found it among [the unanswered](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered).