# Generating images for inclusion in posts

Tags: support, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one add a LaTeX output to a question/answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-does-one-add-a-latex-output-to-a-question-answer)

When generating images to illustrate a phenomenon in a question, I typically end up creating a TeX file, compiling it, opening the PDF, using printscreen to copy to the clipboard, opening an image editor, pasting in, cropping to a sensible size, saving the file and then uploading. There must be a less painful way of doing this...

(I know of LatexIt, but it's Mac-only. I just had a look at [Is there an equation editor for Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52741/is-there-anything-like-latexit-for-windows) and started following up links, but most of the things linked there seem to have pretty poor coverage of maths commands.)

Comment: Why is it a problem to create a TeX file. You’ll need it to post an MWE, anyhow ;-)

Comment: Generating the TeX file isn't the problem --- it's all the other steps.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-does-one-add-a-latex-output-to-a-question-answer, what do you think, @Mohan? Also probably interesting for you: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/how-can-i-provide-a-better-resolution-of-uploaded-pictures-created-with-the-docu

Comment: @doncherry: Yes, it's a duplicate. I am sorry!  (I did search.)  Should I delete the q?

Comment: @Mohan No problem, we'll just close the question and keep it as a pointer to the other question. A tip for searching: Often searching for tags is more efficient than searching for words, so in your case [tag:images] (search term `[images]`).