# How to include latex preview

Tags: discussion, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one add a LaTeX output to a question/answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-does-one-add-a-latex-output-to-a-question-answer)

I have seen that some users include a preview of how the LaTeX code will be rendered.  Are they just including a picture they have compiled and uploaded, or is there a way to do this automatically on this site?

Comment: They include a picture, either a screenshot or a PDF converted to PNG, there is no on-site compilation. See for example http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-does-one-add-a-latex-output-to-a-question-answer and the linked questions.