# How do I include an animated preview of slides on stackexchange?

Tags: discussion

I found explanations of how to include still previews of compiled latex documents on stackexchange [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-does-one-add-a-latex-output-to-a-question-answer), but my question is specifically for slides. Sometimes people include an animated preview of their slides, such as in the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463537/refer-to-last-slide-build-stage-in-overlay-specification). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not a meta question, and the answer is that you can use `convert` from `ImageMagick.org`: `convert -density <density> -delay <delay> -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif`, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/194703).

Comment: Thanks! It just didn't seem to fit within the latex group since it has nothing to do with latex per se. What would be the right forum? Is there a stackexchange stackexchange? :)

Comment: IMHO your question is very related to the one that lead to [the answer in which the conversion was detailed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/194703). It is a very valid LaTeX (as opposed to meta) question how one can create an animated gif from a beamer document. This is independent of whether or not you will use these gifs to illustrate your posts. A valid meta question could be the request to add the information on the conversion to the help system.

Comment: It does, however, make sense to add this information in form of an answer to [this meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-does-one-add-a-latex-output-to-a-question-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I really didn't mean to post in the wrong forum, sorry. I am happy to modify the question into an edit request for the help system if you tell me that's more appropriate, and will add an answer to the other meta question to facilitate people finding the information.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I wrote an answer to the other meta question and wanted to give you credit, but I don't think it worked to link inside the text. Please let me know if there's a better way to refer to your help!

Comment: AlexG deserves credit, not me. ;-)

Comment: The link to his answer worked, so hopefully we'll be okay. :)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think as asked, it's right on meta "how do you post an animation", the non meta question that  is linked is "hos do you make an animation" so an answer here would be "make an animated gif" and then link to the other answer for how to do that

Comment: Related: [How to convert `pstricks` animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764)