# Minimal Working Example (MWE)

Tags: support, mwe

1. How do I pose a Minimal Working Example?
2. How do I plug code into a question?

Comment: Also see [How do I mark code blocks?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) and [How do I mark inline code?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). Also, no matter if on the main site or on meta: Please only ask *one* question per post.

Comment: Straightforward MWE: ```\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at:

- [What is a minimal working example?](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) on minimalbeispiel.de
- [How to make a “minimum example”](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl) in the TeX FAQ
- or the question on this meta site: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

and for the second question:

- [Editing help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code)

right at the beginning.

Comment: The UK TeX FAQ has moved, and is now the English TeX FAQ. Updated link: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl

Comment: @bb010g Thanks! I updated the link.