# How can I ask for more attention if an answer hasn't been provided yet?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, unanswered-questions

In a recent thread of mine ([this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126584/biblatex-n-d-when-no-date-given)), no answer has been provided yet. To give a short outline: I am basically concerned for the issue to produce *n.d.* for citations and bibliography items when no date is given. Apparently it seems impossible because of a bug but I do not have the expertise to tell if that is indeed the case.

Hence I am wondering if I could just comment again to ask for more from the previous commentators? Or is there another guideline for this? If so, a link would be appreciated.

Comment: Although I cannot help you any , I have offered an bounty to bring attention to your Q.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't reluctant to do it myself, just thought I would wait a few more hours to see if there is another way. Also, I imagine Audrey and other biblatex-enthusiasts sometimes just want to have some days off.

Comment: @Werner Agreed, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could offer a [bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to get attention for this question. It will be put to the "featured" tab.

Answer (score 4):

As is stated in the comments, you probably had trouble in getting your question answered because of the lack of a really ***minimal*** [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228); that means the MWE you posted is a little bit too long to debug. 
Even when you shortened it (BTW, you did so in an external pastebin, something that doesn't help either — [edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/126584/edit) your question when you want to change something, so everyone can see it without having to read the whole discussion), you kept in it all the options you were originally passing to `biblatex` as well as all of your style customizations.

Making you MWE short is [a huge step towards the solution of the problem](http://sscce.org/#short): it puts you (and everybody else) on the right track :)

BTW Audrey's last comment is the actual answer to your question; I've just posted it as a community wiki answer.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of the principle behind an MWE. However concerning biblatex, I can't be too careful at this point as I have some time contraints. But this doesn't translate into me imposing "you have to read my whole code" on anyone else of course. It's a somewhat good and meager reason at the same time, for what it's worth.

Comment: @henry I shall award bounty to the answer once 13 hrs delay passes on