# How do I make a "a complete small document"?

Tags: support, mwe

When I asked my [first question on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169353/15717), I was asked to provide "a complete small document that demonstrates the problem."  What is "a complete small document" and how do I make one?

Comment: You mean this [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/15717) then your Q would be a Duplicate of it

Comment: I'm not sure.  I was asked for "a complete small document" and had no idea what it was.

Comment: [Misplaced alignment tab character &](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169353/15717) TeX error that you mentioned may be caused due to many reasons for eg: [Misplaced alignment tab character when building a matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57658/15717) and [what's wrong with my ctable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107716/15717). `&` is used a tab separator in `align`, `tabular` and in `math` environment. Hence an MWE would help to narrow down the possible causes of TeX error. see [LaTeX Companion:B1 Error Messages, Page 904](http://www.informit.com/store/latex-companion-9780201362992)

Comment: ..Contd, `complete small document` means [minimal working example: MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/15717) that reproduces the error.

Comment: @texenthusiast: It is sometimes not a full error (message) but rather some missing command that would (being applied) generate the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although texenthusiast already mentioned the question might be duplicate of [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/15717), it is worth to make some remarks.

Many new users of TeX.SX start with a question about a desired feature or post some fragment(s) of code almost unusable, since this is how `TeX` (a placeholder for `TeX/LaTeX/XeTeX/LuaLaTeX`) does not work, as almost any 'programing' language. It has grammar/syntax rules.

And as such, a small complete document starts with a

```
\documentclass{article}
```

uses some packages (most probably), say

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and eventually some other *preamble* commands (omitted here).

Finally the true document code, beginning (sic!) and ending with

```
\begin{document}
  % Some content in between.
\end{document}
```

This `*.tex` file should reproduce the **error** or the **efforts** what has done so far, not more and not less. This means, that all unnecessary code has to be omitted (preferably) or at least commented out.

So, if your problem has nothing do with

- mathematical markup --> drop all packages concerning math (`amsmath` etc.)
- font issues --> drop all packages using fonts
- hyperlinks  --> omit `hyperref`

etc.

Only the really experienced `TeX` users know or can guess which class/packages should be loaded and sometimes this is even ambiguous since there are varities of possible solutions to a *problem*. A fragment of a code is a starting point, but most time a very crude one.

Finally, this a skeleton of a complete small document:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% \usepackage statements here

%%% Other necessary statements here

\begin{document}
%%% Code for **your** document 
\end{document}
```

Change the documentclass `article` to one you really use.