# Are questions using markdown with LaTeX allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, markdown

Using converters like Pandoc, it is possible to use a substantial amount of LaTeX in a markdown document and convert it to a PDF.

Are questions involving such use cases allowed on this site? And if so, shouldn't there be a separate tag for it?

Comment: As you've no doubt noticed, there's already a markdown tag.  As you may or may not be aware, there is also a pandoc tag.  So, clearly yes?

Comment: @Mark Ok, just clarifying. The word "Markdown" is really general, it doesn't really give me a hint as to what questions it covers. The description of the tag isn't that helpful either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Issues using a variety of software - [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) included - are on topic here as long as the issue relates to (La)TeX in some way. As mentioned in the [TeX - LaTeX Tour page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Ask about...
>
> - Formats like LaTeX, ConTeXt and plain TeX
> - Engines like pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX
> - Distributions like TeX Live, MiKTeX, and MacTeX
> - Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, LyX, etc.
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Since the support for Pandoc might be small (due to the number of questions), I'd suggest spoon-feeding your audience with as much detail as possible, and *always* include a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)...