# Say What? Is there a glossary?

Tags: discussion, acronyms

Many of the posts here have acronyms or initialisms that befuddle me.  After some time perusing other posts with the same acronym, I have been able to deduce most.  However, would it bet possible to add, or is there currently a glossary of acronyms.  Ones I've encounter and been able to deduce (how correctly, I don't know):

- MWE Minimum Working Example
- CV Curriculum Vitae
- DOI i haven't a clue.
- MWEB ibid.

Comment: The OP `:)` is off-topic , BTW `:)` the DOI  is not specific acronym of TeX.SX  `:)`  (IMHO `:)` may be a glossary is a good idea, anyway)

Comment: TY OCWBW  (Thank You  Other Comments Would Be Welcome)  Even if the acronyms are not TeX.SX (Stack eXchange, I suspect)  inclusion in a glossary of terms would be helpful.

Comment: The glossary might be useful for more than just TeX.SX jargon, e.g. differences between TeX, LaTeX, XeTeX, etc.; different file formats (a new user may not know what a `.dvi` file is); and so forth could all be useful.

Comment: [DOI](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=DOI) definition is the first item found by search engines (DuckDuckGo, Google, Bing...).

Comment: Yes, please make an overview (community wiki?) categorized in SX, TeX.SX, LaTeX, others or something like that

Comment: See [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) for a network-wide glossary, but I think it is good to have a list of TeX Stack Exchange-specific terms here. :-)

Comment: Offtopic, but `MWEB` is `Minimal Working Example with Bibliography` http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407

Comment: while everybody is writing about it would be good to have one I just felt free to start with it ;-)

Comment: LSHMSFOAIDMT: Laughing so hard my sombrero falls off and I drop my taco. `:)`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Dictionary: Commonly Used English Acronyms and abbreviations at TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/dictionary-commonly-used-english-acronyms-and-abbreviations-at-tex-sx) although that question doesn't have an answer. Perhaps that one should be closed as a dup of this one (even though it's older).

Answer (score 17):

Here's the (start) of the glossary about TeX.SX specific terms (Well, there might be duplicates with [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms), however)

- CervanTeX

  CervanTeX is the [Spanish-speaking user group](http://www.cervantex.es/), is a group of Spanish-speaking user of TeX.
- CTAN

  The [Comprehensive TeX Archive Network](http://www.ctan.org/), "the cen­tral place for all kinds of ma­te­rial around TeX".
- DANTE

  The [Deutschsprachige Anwendervereinigung TeX e.V.](https://www.dante.de) located in Germany but meant for all German speaking TeX users.
- DOI

  "A [digital object identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) (DOI) is a serial code used to uniquely identify objects. The DOI system is particularly used for electronic documents such as journal articles."
- `foo.tex`

This is actually no acronym, but stands for an arbitrary `TeX` file name to be compiled, i.e. an example file name.

- GuIT

  The [Gruppo Utilizzatori Italiani di TeX](http://www.guitex.org/home/) is the official group for Italian TeX users.
- GUST

  The [Polska Grupa Użytkowników Systemu TeX](http://www.gust.org.pl) "was founded in 1992 to promote in Poland the use of the computer typesetting system called TeX and its companion system Metafont/Metapost for designing fonts."
- LC

  The [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org) site -- a more forum - like site about TeX & Co.
- MWE

  A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) document that shows the issue/request. This includes a compilable document (depending on the `TeX` flavour) and **all** files that are needed to compile the document.
- MWEB

  The MWE with working bibliography file(s)
- MNWE

  This is the *M*inimal *N*on *W*orking *E*xample, i.e. the full code, but that has an issue (typos, syntax errors) but should compile.
- NTG

  The [Nederlandstalige TeX Gebruikersgroep](http://www.ntg.nl/) is the group for Dutch-speaking TeX users.
- OP

  The original poster of the question (or answer) or the original post (depending on context).
- TL

  [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) is a free software distribution for the TeX typesetting system that includes major TeX-related programs, macro packages, and fonts. TeXLive comes in major releases every year (in May or June) is often referred to as TL 2014, TL 2015, etc. Older releases are still available.
- ToC

  The *Table Of Contents*
- TUG

  The [TeX Users Group](https://www.tug.org/), "founded in 1980 to provide an organization for people who are interested in typography and font design, and/or are users of the TeX typesetting system invented by Donald Knuth".
- VtC

  **Vote to Close** (this acronym may exist on other sites as well, of course)

Comment: you might want to note that a "working" example doesn't actually have to "work".  it just needs to be compilable, and give the same result that the question is asking about.  on the other hand,  a link to [What makes a good MWE?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343) might suffice rather than excess verbiage.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Well, I had the MNWE in mind

Comment: i;m sure *you* did!  but this is a glossary to help the newbie, not us old fogies who write documentation that may not get read.  (i even promise to help with additions to the list as soon as the upcoming issue of tugboat has been sent to the printer.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: This is why I made it CW ... any body can edit it

Comment: OP goes back a long way and isn't specific to TeX-sx, StackExchange or TeX.

Comment: @JosephWright: True, but there might be users that are not active in other communities. Anyway, it's a CW, anybody can change the list

Comment: There's a difference between O.P. and OP??

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: Yes, you can't edit the person who posted the question or the answer ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, there is social engineering, but at least it is not as easy to edit the person compared to their post. ;)

Comment: LC is not more forum like, it is a classical discussion forum. Has pros and cons in relation to a QA site.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Please change it to the correct description then.