# How do I get reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, reputation

Why is there no [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation) tag?

I tried to `enter a new tag`, but only users with a high reputation as 300 are able to generate a new one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please have a look to page https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: What tag do you want to add?

Comment: here on tex.meta (where this question belongs, because it is not about tex but about the website tex.se) is already a tag `reputation`: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation

Comment: Answer a TikZ - related question and you will be flooded with reputation ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Please have a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/121799). The data does not necessarily support this statement.

Comment: @marmot: That doesn't convince me. Most top users answer have answers in almost any tag and answer basically any question they can grip, so it's naturally that they will have a lot of rep, by stray votes or having just the advantage of being a top user .... so they pile up more rep ... it's a 'vicious' circle...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree on the circle but what does that have to do with the observation that the data does not support the statement that `tikz-pgf` posts draw particularly many votes? My comment was only that I fail to see any data supporting "Answer a TikZ - related question and you will be flooded with reputation". According to moewe's analysis there are other tags which give more reputation on average.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, by the way, that there is a reputation requirement to create new tags for a reason. Tags are meant to very broadly indicate the theme of a question. They're more like the section your question would go in in a library. Many people new to the site want to create all kinds of overly specific tags (I'm not saying you would, possibly you intended to create a tag we still need). Generally the tags we have at the moment are more than sufficient and even if the tag you had in mind would be nice, the question you were asking will surely be at home in any existing tag for now

Comment: If you think an important tag is missing you could open a question here on meta to discuss it. If people agree they may create the tag for you. If you are writing a question and think a tag is missing, add a comment or a small footnote in the question itself and someone who can create the tag may be so nice to retag your question with the new tag. If you are asking for a tag "reputation" on the main site, that would probably not be very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In essence, you receive reputation by contributing to the main site. This is achieved by any one of the following:

- Ask a question that shows you've done some research, but still need help solving. This should include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) *highlighting* the main problem and be isolated to that problem *only*. Upvotes on questions earn you +5 in reputation.
- Write up [a good answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/168244) to a question. Upvotes on answers earn you +10 in reputation.
- Write up [a great answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/168244) and have it accepted by the questioner. Accepted answers receive +15 reputation.
- Write up [an awesome answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/168244) and be awarded a bounty by some donor (questioner or otherwise). Bounties can earn you anywhere from 50-500 per award.
- Suggest edits to existing posts or tag wiki's that improve the content. Accepted edits receive +2 reputation, [up to +1,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/168244).
- Join a site while having at least 200 reputation on another. This automatically earns you an association bonus of +100 reputation on the newly-joined site.

Related/reference:

- [How can I get reputation? I can't seem to gain any](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/150010/168244)
- [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/168244)
- [What is the best way to increase my reputation and privileges?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/146472/168244)
- [The surest way to gain lots of reputation on Stack Overflow - ask questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/33398/168244)
- [How do I write a good answer to a question?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/168244)
- [How does "Reputation" work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/168244)