# Breaking the language barrier How to provide guidance for mwe in another language

Tags: support, mwe

I was dismayed nay surprised to find that I cannot web translate a page from this site due to its underlying structure.

My intent was to point a shared link to a translator for the MWE guidance but that failed in my choice of translator due to the way this "framing" site is built. 
Thus can totally understand why non english students hit their head on the wall when given a link to the standard request for a MWE

Can anyone provide a link to any good clear "SIMPLE" (translatable) web page (i.e. not this site) with "How to build a MWE ?"

In my browser Google OR Yandex translate will fail miserably

[image]

**ONLY showing a blank page** when OK is clicked

**Bing will not show a message and will proceed** as intended with the same MWE url

https://www.translatoruser.net/proxy.ashx?&to=ru&csId=5adc1aee-4457-44ed-8a5e-74ca3a4c9b17&usId=264c56b3-5e68-4bd4-b593-e186e39f7dde&orefd=www.bing.com&ac=true&bvrpx=true&bvrpp=&dt=2019%2F2%2F2%2014%3A50&h=nDudiGEuT_hwQPH6VP9Pa1-2DCDTvfKo&a=HTTPS%3A%2F%2FTeX.meta.StackExchange.com%2Fquestions%2F228%2FIve-Just-Been-Asked-to-write-a-Minimal-example-What-Is-That

Comment: http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/ has an explanation in German and English. Not sure how well suited it is for automatic translation, though.

Comment: mowe that is great see https://translate.yandex.com/translate?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.minimalbeispiel.de%2Fmini-en.html&lang=en-ru care to give that as an answer ?

Comment: Apparently https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/was-ist-ein-vollstandiges-minimalbeispiel-oder-kurz-vm-und-wie-erstelle-ich-dieses  (in German) can also be translated (I checked with Dutch, but I wouldn't know how well this translates into say, Russian or Portuguese)

Comment: With the Chrome web browser, the translation is automatic. Personally, I use deepl.com by making a copy and paste and that's no problem. The problem is the translation of technical terms that are most often approximate or false and this complicates understanding.

Comment: Actually I would assume, that anyone, that uses TeX etc. and recognizes that basically every command name is some kind of English that those users know enough of English language to understand some instructions in English or can express them in a clear way what the question is about. My knowledge of French or Spanish is very limited, so I refrain from posting anything on French or Spanish sites, because I know about my limitations

Comment: @ChristianHupfer whilst I agree with your sentiment and have on occasion tried pig-Russian (with abysmal failure) I have trasliterated some French and Irish reasonably (neither of which I know) and got my knuckles wrapped for saying all languages are equal but some are more equal than others by offering the insurmountable barrier is idiomacy. Thus how is the word Mwe universally recognisable as a request for "change your question" when what the user has is an UN-mwe. Certainly faced with trying to question my failings in another tongue I would not know their equivalent abbreviations.

Answer (score 6):

There are several non-TeX.SX resources out there that explain the process of creating MWEs

- https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl (English)
- http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/ (German and English)
- https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/was-ist-ein-vollstandiges-minimalbeispiel-oder-kurz-vm-und-wie-erstelle-ich-dieses (German, could be shortened to https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/)
- https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/ (English)
- https://texnique.fr/osqa/faq/#custom-id-ecm (French)
- https://www.gutenberg.eu.org/ECM (very short in French)

That said, the translation service of a well-known search engine also worked for me on our own [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

I checked a few of those with Dutch and got reasonable results (as far as I can tell), but I wouldn't know how the texts translate into languages further from German or English. With technical advice like this bad translations can cause more frustration and confusion...

---

- General, non-TeX advice is at http://sscce.org/

Comment: :-) how did you accept your answer ?? anyway Apart from the user choice of browser (with or without an inbuilt translator) some translators are more equal than others for some structures such as stack exchange thus best to give alternative links. My remaining problem is the length of TWO shared links can easily exceed the comments allowance so I can add at this point 220 chars but inserting JUST ONE  translator link to is too long by 147 characters DUH

Comment: If you want to add also a link for Italian, here it is (pdf): http://www.guitex.org/home/images/doc/GuideGuIT/guidaemc.pdf

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I hadn't initially planned on adding a lot of languages and I don't know if a PDF fits the bill of being easily auto-translated. I think, however, that a question and answer listing non-English resources for MWEs might be worthwhile. Perhaps you want to ask a new one?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like German to me, you didn't say which translation site you used.

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&tl=de&u=https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that&xid=25657,15700022,15700186,15700191,15700248&usg=ALkJrhgOadOjn1Q8fq89tAC3o_YZwOlpog

Comment: Fails for me see edited question, Yandex also has problems best option seems to be Bing

Comment: @KJO that's very odd, I just tested that link in firefox and chrome and it works in either. Do you have some extra security plugins installed?

Comment: No just the ancient default third world explorer :-)

Comment: @KJO seems then that the issue is mostly in your choice of browser rather than in the stackexchange page or the translator.  The link in this answer works in firefox, Chrome, Edge and Internet Explorer as far as I can tell.

Comment: Agreed since **all examples** on this page fail to translate (staying in English) in my **Windows 10 Firefox** too and **Edge gives me the message but proceeds to Bing link** in my question **but not your google one** so it must be my systems security  that rejects most redirected links

Comment: Ok spending a long time relaxing all my security in Firefox I eventually allowed google to analyse my actions, track me and read my inside leg measurement so I could proceed to your google page as translated in German so have to presume its secure system users that are thwarted.