# How to reduce (prune) my code so it becomes a MWE (Minimal Working Example)?

Tags: discussion, mwe

Several times I saw newcomers struggeling with posting the right amount of code, which causes them problems.

Many time they are [linked to MWE advice like this one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/245790), but certainly will feel overwhelmed.

How to do it step by step,

- starting with ones own problematic code,
- showing enough to replicate the problem (by copy and compile)
- and leave out irrelevant parts?