# FAQ request: encourage use of [big-list] meta-tag

Tags: feature-request, faq, tagging, big-list

[The *About meta-tagging* qn](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/about-meta-tagging) tried to help us reach a policy on meta-tags.  I'm not convinced by Jeff's argument, but I'm relaxed about losing most of them, with the single exception of the [`[big-list]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) tag.

An example: on [the *Showcase of beautiful typography done in LaTeX* question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-latex), Robert Cartaino commented:

> When you are asking users to contribute to a list of answers, the question should be marked 
>   [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I have converted this question.

Such questions have a special status, as experienced SO and MO users will know.  It is good and not harmful to tag these questions [big-list], as is common practice on MO but not SO, because:

1. It helps beginners understand what is expected of questions if we have this tag;
2. In case there is resistance to CW-ifying such a question, it helps to be able to point at the questions covered by the [big-list] tag;
3. It is not (unlike the examples Jeff gave) subjective in its application, rather its application is crystal clear;
4. I often find it useful on MO in searching to restrict searches so that they either include the tag or exclude it, and I expect other MO users find this useful too.

**I propose that we explictly encourage applying [big-list] to this sort of question in our FAQ**, even if our FAQ ends up discouraging all other meta-tags.

Comment: I was undecided but I agree with your rationale here (and the votes show a number of people already agree too). Could you add this to the question with [our set of tags](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302/our-set-of-tags).

Comment: @Juan: Edited.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Perhaps I'm old-fashioned, but I think these questions belong in the FAQ proper (www.tex.ac.uk/faq).