# What to do with the 'latex' tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

As we now have moderators, it's probably a good time to address the 'latex' tag. There are a few questions where this does seem to make sense (such as LaTeX *versus* ConTeXt *versus* plain *versus* ...). However, the general feeling seems to be that the tag shouldn't be used for most questions simply as they are about LaTeX. So do we retain it for those cases or drop it entirely, and if so is there a good replacement for the cases which are about LaTeX in general?

**Edit:** I wanted to bump this question to raise again the issue of how can we finally get rid of this tag. Me (and probably some others) have been (according to the discussion bellow) slowly fixing `latex` tagged questions while trying not to flood the front page with these questions. So how should we go about it?

1. Should we keep doing this micro-edits and try to keep an eye so that new questions are tagged appropriately?
2. Should we request the feature of a tag kill-switch available to moderators?
3. Or should we ask for a feature where some edits can be marked as “minor” so that they don't promote questions to the front-page again?

Any thoughts on how to proceed? - Juan

Comment: How about `latex-misc` or something similar? I also like `latex-core` that Juan proposed for questions relating to the internals of LaTeX.

Comment: Another question: In the event that LaTeX 3 is released and this site is still around, how will we distinguish between LaTeX2e and LaTeX3? How likely is it that at some point a different macro set (say, ConTeXt) will be more popular than LaTeX and the "by default the question is about LaTeX2e" motto doesn't apply anymore?

Comment: I think should deal with 'the way the world is now'! It will take a while (years) for people to adopt LaTeX3 even if/after it is released. The `latex3` tag should be okay for this eventuality, at least for a long time to come.

Comment: We seem to be generally of one mind on this: I may make a start later today.

Comment: I think all `latex-general` questions have been retagged, but I can't think of any useful tag for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-can-i-produce-exercises-in-one-part-of-a-latex-document-with-selected-answers

Comment: Perhaps `exercises` or `answers`? Now, has anyone seen a way to 'kill' a tag without editing every single occurrence separately?

Comment: Can't mods do that?

Comment: I've asked on the mod-only part of SO: apparently only the SO team can delete tags. So it's either a quick request to them or some 'by hand' edits.

Comment: I'd prefer the request, so that we don't flood the start page.

Comment: Agree entirely: now, how do we get the SO people to do this :-)

Comment: I started to delete the `latex` tags one by one (occasionally replacing them with `latex-general`) and after about a dozen edits noticed the "flooding the start page"-effect. I'll stop for now, but will at least look for questions where the `latex-general` tag is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, it seems only the SO people can deal with this. The moderators can't do it without the same problem: we will be asking for the 'latex' tag to be removed!

Comment: How about removing the tag from just a handful of questions each day, preferably spread over the day? So that there is no flooding. If you want, I could do that over the next week.

Comment: I think that retagging about half a dozen questions per day should be tolerable. At the moment, there are still 49 questions tagged with `LaTeX`, and as long as the tag exists, it will be occasionally used for new questions.

Comment: Just have an administrator (developer?) ban the `latex` tag, if you're so intent on it not existing...

Comment: @Sam: Is that even possible?

Comment: @Caramdir: I've read stuff on meta.SO that lead me to believe that it is possible

Answer (score 5):

For a question about LaTeX in general this tag is appropriate, but it seems too natural to choose a [latex] tag for a more specific question as well. We might avoid it by introducing a [latex-general] tag for such general discussions. Its intention is very obvious and [latex] could be dropped.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I guess the best plan would be to find the places where such a tag does apply, sort them out then look to remove the `latex` tag.

Comment: I also like this idea very much, drop `latex` and keep both `latex-general` and `latex-core` for the cases when such a tag *is* needed.

Comment: This is obviously going to be one for the FAQ! One thing is that I'd prefer `latex-kernel` for stuff relating to the internals of LaTeX.