# Link to editing help?

Tags: feature-request

When asking a question, a sidebar provides an editing quick reference, and clearly points to the full manual.  When answering a question, the "?" visual icon leads to the manual.

At this site (as apparently with other StackExchange sites) the manual is available at https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help but I couldn't find a link to it anywhere on the site itself.  The MO FAQ points to the editing manual, and I found this useful.  I tend to ignore small visual icons, instead focusing on the textual elements, and didn't immediately see how to find editing help when composing an answer.

Could a link be added to the FAQ?

Comment: Yes, it'd be very good to have the link in FAQ. Unfortunately, the manual does not explain an issue that I have encountered frequently: sometimes backslashes and other special characters need to be escaped. In particular in the case of comments (which don't provide any preview), it tends to be annoying trial-and-error. The bottom of http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax seems to contain a list of the special characters that can be (and sometimes need to be) escaped with a backslash. Perhaps we could explain this in the FAQ, too?

Comment: A link to the markdown syntax would definitely be useful.

Comment: @Jukka: I think the backslashes on comments are really a bug http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168/backslash-in-ticks-in-comments

Comment: @Jukka: The list provided at your link is too long. Only `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `*` _can_ be escaped (meaning that a backslash in front of them gets eaten), and `\`` _must_ be escaped unless you _only_ have a `\`` in backticks, or the backtick is followed by a letter. Have a look at [this post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863/1235).

Comment: @Jukka: OK, the backslash escaping [is now disabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments/79218#79218) except for the backtick.