# How do you accept an answer?

Tags: support, accepting

I have been "accepting answers" to my questions by up voting the good answers received for my questions.  However, I have a 0% accept rate. :(

Apparently, I do not know how to accept answers.

Comment: Related reference: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/168244)

Comment: From the Help Centre: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! you accept an answer by clicking on the green checkmark next to the answer. Voting up good answers is a way of saying it is a good answer, but there can be many good answers, but only one accepted answer.

Thanks for caring!

Here's what an unaccepted and an accepted answer looks like:

[image] [image]

and here's that same answer before and after an upvote:

[image] [image]

There's a brief period ([15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50697)) immediately after asking the question when you can't accept an answer.

Comment: To add on this: accordant to the stack exchange staff you should accept the answer which helped you the most. There might be the situation that another answer is actually technical more correct or more popular. Of course, you have the last say which question you accept or if you accept any answer so far.

Comment: Shouldn;t that be "you accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark"?

Answer (score 18):

There's another difference between upvoting and accepting: After a short "grace" period, an upvote can't be undone (unless the upvoted answer has been edited). In contrast, an accepted answer can be "un-accepted" any time later. (A valid reason for doing so is that a new "late" answer supersedes the previously accepted one.)

Answer (score 14):

Associated with accepting an answer (clicking on the arrow below the voting buttons) is an added bonus - **reputation**! If you read the main site FAQ entry on [What is reputation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you'll note that when accepting an answer, the acceptor receives **+2** in reputation.

Comment: and the "acceptee" recieves **+15**, so with **+10** for up-vote, you can give a total **+25** to the author of the answer you consider the most helpful! :)