# Own answers should be possible to be accepted after some(?) votes of commited tex.se users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepting, answers

I really do *not* vote up for own questions, own answers and own everything else where voting or any kind of a counted positive commenting is applicable.  Theoretically, given that I won't rethink my personal attitude against self-voting, and no more answers than my own -- to own question(s) -- will be provided, this can lead to a question (e.g. [How to apply alternate row coloring in a longtable in LyX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61747/8272)) which will never receive an accepted answer!

Of course, this is unlikely to happen for questions of high importance that concern a lot of people.  But does this really matter?  What about questions that won't gain much attention?

I do think that all usefully answered questions, should be paired with accepted answers. This, however, is not a strong(er) argument for me to re-think my skepsis about not voting up for own posts.

Would it be useful to give-away my voting right in this occasion to others? Maybe a mechanism could be activated and automatically accept an own answer to own question, if, this (own) answer has received some(?) votes by high-rep users (--who is considered a high-rep user anyway?) or committed tex.se users that have earned specific badges.

Comment: You *can't* upvote your own questions/answers, the system won't let you. And if you accept your own answer (perfectly OK), you won't get any rep for it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. TeX.SE is a democratic community :-)

Comment: You will be able to accept your answer only after some time has passed (I guess 6 hours).

Comment: @percuse I don't want to accept (any of) my answer(s) :-)

Comment: @percusse, as I commented below, I'll probably adjust my view against self-accepting answers.

Comment: I feel it was worthy to ask this question. I was activated to read several stuff and learn more about the way SE is designed and works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Note: the following answer is a combination of explanations and arguments provided by [Alan Munn](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn), [Caramdir](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/83/caramdir) and others.]

By definition, one should always accept the answer that was mostly helpful in solving a problem.  If the most helpful answer is one's own answer, then it should be accepted.  Answering (and accepting answers for) own questions doesn't gain any reputation.  Nevertheless, the site improves because accepted answers are a sign that answers were helpful (at least for someone).  Therefore, answering own questions and accepting them is explicitly encouraged.  In contrast, the attitude against accepting own answers, contradicts, in a way, the spirit of the site.

**Keep in mind that** one:

- cannot upvote own questions
- cannot vote for own answers
- has to wait some time before allowed to accept own answers (this is to give others the chance to write better answers and to keep people from gaming the system, see also [Accept Your Own Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) at SE blog)
- can (and should) accept own answers that helped
- won't get any +rep from accepting own answers
- might, however, get the self-learner badge

**Detailed argumentation:**

Implementing the suggested mechanism is probably not a good idea (not to mention it is unlikely to ever be implemented by the Stackexchange powers that be).  **First,** as mentioned in the comments, accepting an answer is not the same as upvoting an answer, so when one accepts an answer (even his/her own) no vote is conferred.  **Second,** if there are multiple answers to a question, the answer with the most upvotes is not necessarily the best answer for the questioner (or generally).  **Third,** a new answer might be added later, and even with a few votes, this answer may well be one that the questioner would like to accept, even though it has fewer votes.  **Consequently,** having any kind of automatic system that would automatically accept high voted answers, is not a good idea as it would interfere with the above mentioned points.

See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/2693) for some more discussion on accepting answers.

Comment: Accepted my "own" answer...  :-)

Answer (score 14):

I don't think this is a good idea (not to mention it is unlikely to ever be implemented by the Stackexchange powers that be).

First, as has been mentioned in the comments, *accepting* an answer is not the same as *upvoting* an answer, so when you accept an answer (even your own) no vote it conferred. Consequently, you can't ever vote for your own answer, but you *can* (and should) accept it if it is the answer that helped you. (See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/2693) for some more discussion on accepting answers.)

Second, if there are multiple answers to a question, the answer with the most upvotes is not necessarily the best answer for you as the questioner (or generally). So any system that would automatically accept high voted answers is not a good idea.

Third, a new answer might be added later, and even with a few votes, this answer may well be one that you would like to accept, even though it has fewer votes.  Again, having any kind of automatic system would interfere with this.

So the bottom line is: it's perfectly fine to accept your own answers, because you don't gain any reputation from doing so, but the site improves because accepted answers are a sign that the answer worked (at least for someone).

Comment: "...any system that would automatically accept high voted answers is not a good idea.": This is true!

Comment: I'll try to re-think over, after having read your last sentence. Specifically "...the site improves because accepted answers are a sign that the answer worked (at least for someone)".

Answer (score 12):

Pretty much by definition you *should* accept the answer that helped you the most. If that answer is your own answer then you should accept that. Thus your attitude against accepting your own answer is against the spirit of the site.

Note that you can never upvote your own question and won't get any +rep from accepting your own answer. You might however get the [self-learner badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/14/self-learner). You might also have to wait some amount of time before being allowed to accept your own answer (this is to give others the chance to write better answers and to keep people from gaming the system).

Again: answering your own questions is [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and you should *always* accept the answer that best solved your problem.

Comment: you provided a short and clear answer, accompanied by links with related information.  I find, however, Alan Munn's last sentence more convincing.  I am unsure whose answer I should accept :-).  I'll wait a bit.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: This is meta, so it doesn't really matter. You don't really need to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the title of this question is your real concern:

> Own answers should be possible to be accepted after some(?) votes of commited tex.se users

Then the answer is simple: You *can* accept your own answer, just you have to wait 2 days before the system allows you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As clearly expressed in the question, I consider that some number of positive votes casted by committed tex.se users, could activate an accepting-answer mechanism when:

1. both answer and question belong to the same user
2. there is strictly no up-vote from the OP for both own question and own answer
3. the question itself receives some minimum of up-votes (e.g. 10, regardless the reputation of the users)
4. no other answers are given to the question
5. in case other answers are given *and* they receive(d) less votes than the answer of the OP
6. specific number of positive votes given by high(er)-rep users or users with specific badges (no clue yet which!)
7. no flagging has been applied at any time
8. (more restrictions to think... ?)

Comment: Regarding 2: That doesn't work anyway, you can't upvote your own posts (questions, answers, comments). In a situation like the one you describe with this set of rules, I really don't understand why you wouldn't just accept your own answer? You're not going to get any reputation out of it, it would just serve to make the site cleaner, because people can see that the question has a satisfactory answer.

Comment: This whole idea seems pointless to me. How many questions posted by a member who objects to accepting his/her own answer satisfy all of the above conditions? Zero would be my guess.

Comment: @IanThompson In my question, I clearly write what _theoretically_ can happen. And the whole idea is about a consensus-based (or democratic (?) if I may say so) Q&A-discussion system. It is not bad, in my opinion, to put this kind of theoretical questions. Anyway, I am slowly convincing myself that I too should accept an answer of mine if there is no better alternative to it. I am really happy to read so different comments and answers.

Comment: @Jake and others, I really have never tried to upvote my own posts! :D

Comment: *Theoretically* I might be abducted by aliens on my way to work. I'm not going to spend time worrying about what to do if that happens, though.

Comment: If several people would not spent time _worrying_ what would happen if... it could be that we would not have the internet today.

Comment: grrr... can't vote down my own answer!