# Multiple questions or single question?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, policy

When working on a document, I often end up with multiple questions. Should I club all the related questions together and ask a single question or break them into separate questions. All the questions are specific about how to do something, but may or may not affect the answer to other questions (because I do not know the answer).

For example, recently I was working on a plot and needed help with annotations. I had two questions,

1. how to [generate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73578/annotating-family-of-curves-in-pgfplot) the annotations and
2. how to adjust their placement based on the value of the annotation.

I never got around to asking the second question but for future reference should I combine such questions? Or If I am asking multiple questions should I reference the other questions, which I had but many not be relevant for the answer?

Comment: Thank you for being so considerate to ask this question here! A lot of people would've just asked their questions in whatever way, not really caring about the appropriate grouping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is usually best to ask *single*, *self-contained* questions *and* include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. You could describe your end-goal in an attempt to guide answers. However, think of this site as a destination where not only *you* can find answers, but also *others*. Future visitors may not have the same end-goal as you, and therefore might not be interested in wading through a complicated description of a big, multi-stage question/problem.

If you have an additional question that could not be answered in your first, consider asking a follow-up question. [Follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) (new questions) are more than welcome! Even though you have a bigger picture in mind, consider accepting the answer that helped you most with each of the questions asked (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)) as you move this Q&A journey towards your end-goal.

Also, if you consider some of the questions en-route to be too small for asking, there's always the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41) were skilled regulars hang out and exchange ideas.

<sub>Some of the above are snippets from [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/5764) - comments scattered across this network to help improve the quality.</sub>