# Correct "TeX.SX" section of the site FAQ

Tags: feature-request

Currently, the ["What kind of questions can I ask here?" section of the site FAQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) reads:

> Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX.SX is for...

However, this is incorrect, as the common nomenclature in use to indicate Stack Exchange is SE, *not* SX.  The sentence *should* read:

> Welcome to TeX.SE! TeX.SE is for...

Even better, it should be consistent of other areas of the site and not use an abbreviation at all, and say "Stack Exchange":

> Welcome to TeX - Stack Exchange! TeX - Stack Exchange is for...

As per other `/faq` sections on the Stack Exchange network such as [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) (emphasis mine):

> [Parenting - **Stack Exchange** is for...](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

And Programmers (again, emphasis mine):

> [Programmers - **Stack Exchange** is a site...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Among others.

Comment: Note there is no `site-faq` tag, which distinguishes between the `/faq` part of the site and questions on meta tagged `faq`.  This question should be tagged with the former (see [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-faq)).

Comment: Regarding the SE/SX abbreviation, the use of SX is justified in [Trivial point about tex.se vs. tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/470/3323)

Comment: @diabonas Given the lack of responses and upvotes on responses, I wouldn't call it *justified* necessarily.  Additionally, I respect that different sites in the Stack Exchange network have their own ways of doing things, but the representation of the network *consistently and as a whole* is something that is decided from the top down (e.g. you couldn't modify the Stack Exchange icon to be reflective of TeX, bubbles is bubbles).  It's about consistent representation across the network, and this is an area (an important one, I'd argue) where the deviation is improper and possibly harmful.

Comment: @diabonas I'll also note that the link you've given uses the fact that .se is a top-level domain to prove it's point.  The same can be said about many other sites in the Stack Exchange network.  Just because SE is a top-level domain doesn't invalidate the use of SE as an abbreviation for Stack Exchange; it would invalidate that use across the *entire* network.

Comment: Maybe "justified" is too strong - excuse my poor English, I wanted to express something like "it's explained why it is at it is". However, I think it is a valid point - but I completely agree with you that this concerns the whole Stack Exchange network, so it probably http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ would be the best place for clarification.

Comment: @diabonas meta.SO isn't the appropriate place for this as it deals with the representation of Stack Exchange on TeX.  If Tex was an example of this kind of representation *everywhere* and one wanted to change it, then meta.SO would be the more appropriate place.  Right now, TeX is the outlier.

Comment: That's what I meant - *If* the OP of the linked question was right and SX should be preferred over SE, then it should be changed for all sites of the network.

Comment: I like the `sx` suffix, it makes us look cool. `:)` Funny note: the `X` in `TeX` doesn't sound like `X` at all, which makes this form way cooler. `:)`

Comment: This "question" (where's the question mark?) has now been superseded by http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/change-tex-latex-stack-exchange-to-tex-stack-exchange and so should be closed.

Answer (score 8):

I think the best approach here is, as you say, to avoid an abbreviation in the FAQ at all and put 'TeX - Stack Exchange' (perhaps without the repetition).

> [Welcome to TeX –­ Stack Exchange!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This site is ...

Comment: Using 'TeX - LaTeX - ...' is consistent with http://tex.stackexchange.com/about and with the page title for the main page.

Comment: Actually, we might want to avoid 'LaTeX' here: I'll open a separate question

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/change-tex-latex-stack-exchange-to-tex-stack-exchange

Comment: I've implemented a slightly modified version of this change: does this [meta-tag:status-completed] this question or should that be left to the linked one?